# Let's build a community FAQ

Tags: discussion

Our community FAQ is currently.... quite lacking.

[image: screenshot]

The first two are okay, but the third one isn't even supposed to have the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag (mods: please remove it).

So, let's start building our FAQ!

Here's a few things we could start with off the top of my head:

- [Standard "loopholes" that are no longer funny](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/3808) (I've went ahead and tagged this [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) to get things started)
- A post mentioning that code golfs should usually be language-agnostic (any programming language allowed)
- What format should the answers be in? (Language and score on a header, then code block and preferrably explanation below)
- A general sandbox post that explains about the sandbox and links to the latest version. This would be good because 1. It would be less work to switch sandboxes and 2. All that sandbox boilerplate could go away. Also, 3. Old sandbox links would still work and not require tons of clicking to find the latest one.
- etc.

Comment: Trivia: I created the [language-agnostic](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/language-agnostic/info) tag on Stack Overflow, [back in the day](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19/13). That's how much [I care about it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225428/13). :-D

Comment: BTW, I'm happy to periodically monitor for [tag:faq-proposed] and upgrade to [tag:faq] as necessary.

Comment: What about this: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/765/9498 ?

Comment: If this is tagged [faq-proposed], why is it not tagged [faq-proposed]?

Comment: @Quincunx "If this is X, why is it not X?" doesn't seem to make much logical sense. What are you talking about?

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I misread. I thought that Doorknob marked this question as [faq-proposed], but it wasn't on there. I realize now that Doorknob was talking about Standard Loopholes.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young so you're the one to blame for all those mistagged [regex] [language-agnostic] questions! :P

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking it would be a good idea to have an FAQ Sandbox. Given the [sentiment against FAQs being easy to edit](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1280/community-faq-for-programming-puzzles-code-golf) it makes sense to have a place to whip the question and proposed answer into shape.