# Community FAQ for Code Golf and Coding Challenges

Tags: support, faq

## Community FAQ

**For the Code Golf and Coding Challenges site**

For official guidance from Stack Exchange, visit the [Help Center](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help).

### General information

- [Welcome to Code Golf and Coding Challenges Stack Exchange!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833)
- [How does this site work?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13944/66833)
- [Useful External Resources](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10351/66833)

### Posting Challenges

- [What details should always be given for a code golf task?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/93)
- [What makes winning criteria "objective"?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/305)
- [Template For Challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1511)
- [Where should non-challenge questions go?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1555)
- [How does the Sandbox work? How do I use it?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2056)
- [Things to consider when creating a challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5582)
- [Things to avoid when writing challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8047)
- [Let's decide what kind of non-challenge questions we want once and for all](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1723)
- [Are two questions duplicates if they have different scoring rules?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/777)
- [How long should I wait before accepting an answer?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2035)
- [What are the winning criteria I can use for my challenge?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22371)
- [Standard definitions of terms within specifications](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1324)

### Posting Solutions

- [Loopholes that are forbidden by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061)
- [How to count bytes FAQ](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10145)
- [Interpretation of Truthy/Falsey](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2190)
- [Definitive policy about answers not meeting the challenge specification](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7987)
- [Default for Code Golf: Input/Output methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447)
- [Default for Code Golf: Program, Function or Snippet?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419)
- [New users' guides to golfing rules in specific languages](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11924)
- [Should submissions be allowed to exit with an error?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4780)
- [General rules for custom languages and libraries](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10225)

#### Interacting with the site

- [What are our specific abbreviations and terms?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12537)
- [Is it OK to promote my own posts in chat?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10184)
- [How can I incorporate good-looking mathematical exposition into my question/answer?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1301)

---

### Is your question not part of the FAQ?

First look at questions tagged [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) to see if there is a question not in this index that might have the answer you seek. If you still can't find an answer, then see the following instructions for proposing an FAQ question.

#### How can a question be added to this FAQ?

- Ask only the question, stated plainly and simply, in the question body.
  The answer goes in an answer.
- **Link back** to this index. Paste this at the end of the question:

  ```
   [Return to FAQ index](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1280)
  ```
- Tag as [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) and [support](/questions/tagged/support).  When a post seems
  to hit a mature state, it will have [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) added by a moderator.
- Flag for a moderator to mark **community wiki**.  Any FAQ post not yet
  community wiki should be made into a community wiki.
- After the post has the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag added to it, add a link in the above [table of contents](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1280).

Comment: Why CW-ify? I don't see that FAQs need to be easy to edit.

Comment: I've added the [tag:faq] tag. I agree with Peter that it doesn't need to be easy to edit. ;-)

Comment: @Chris Because... it's a **community** faq? It's supposed to be made by the community. Also, http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225807/180276

Comment: @Doorknob Very well.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: What should we do now with the FAQ posts? I flagged some of them with reason "Please mark this as CW because it is a FAQ post", but these flags were marked as helpful **and** got a "As mentioned by Peter Taylor, there's no need to CW FAQ posts." reason, but this reason looks more like a decline reason, and not as a reason for helpful flags.

Comment: @ProgramFOX I CW'd them, that's what happened to those posts. As for the flags themselves, I mark them as helpful if the flagger has a point, even if I don't actually implement what they request. (Unfortunately I don't get the same latitude for comment flags: if you dismiss a comment flag, it's considered declined.)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: OK, thanks!

Comment: Input and output formats ? I have seen it a 100 times but litteraly can't find it right now.