# Standard definitions of terms within specifications

Tags: discussion, faq, policy, defaults, specification

Quite often I find that I am repeating myself when creating a challenge. For example, usually I have to retype the definition of "random" in all of my posts, or I have to specify the same thing about how reasonable input and output can be provided in every challenge.

This post is meant to be a collection of "standard" definitions that may be assumed in every question, and do not need to be specified within the challenge. Definitions will apply once the post with the defintion has a score of +5 or more, and it has at least twice as many upvotes as downvotes.

Comment: I don't think the "at least twice as many upvotes as downvotes" is a good idea - if a comment has only one upvote but no downvotes, does that mean it should be considered as a standard definition?

Comment: @ace "...has a score of +5 or more, and..."

Comment: Oops... sorry, I somehow read this as "+5 or more, or..." My bad.

Comment: @Doorknob: You typed *defintions* in the title.

Comment: For users like me, I don't know if a definition has twice as many upvotes as downvotes.  We either need to have "Accepted" next to the title, or not include that requirement.

Answer (score 25):

## "random"

The term "random" means that you may:

1. Use your language's built-in random number generator,
2. Use `/dev/random`, or
3. Create a RNG that is equivalent to a standard RNG (such as the Mersenne Twister).

Comment: How about mandating a call to `srand()` or its equivalent? By default, I always get 16807 from the first call to `rand()`, which is obviously quite the opposite of random.

Comment: I've seen some people using `Date()` as `random()` because it is shorter, is there any consensus about that? Whether it is right or not?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Just to let you know, that has now been asked as a [separate meta question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13029/is-the-current-time-or-date-with-modulo-random-enough).

Comment: Is Python's `id` considered random?

Comment: I think the best would be to avoid _random_ altogether. A sufficiently random datum is given as _an_ _input_, too, so implementors do not have to worry whether _their_ implementation of obtaining a random datum is random _enough_. This shifts the focus away from the sub-task of getting a random datum, and also programming languages that do not have a built‑in RNG can reasonably compete.

Answer (score 19):

## "uniformly random"

There are two distinct things to define for "uniform" (in the context of uniformly distributed random variables).

1. If "uniform" is ***not*** specified, then "random" does not imply uniformly random.
2. If "uniform" ***is*** specified, the standard PRNG (pseudo random number generator) of your programming language can be assumed uniform.

#### Examples

- **Output a random integer from 1 to 5:**
  It does not matter if 2 is output with higher probability than 3.
- **Output a uniformly random integer from 1 to 5:**
  The probability of each of 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 must be 0.2, but a slight deviation from this due to the implementation of random is fine (*provided that the implementation is not of a different distribution - you can't use a normal distribution to save bytes*).
- **Output a uniformly random point on a disk:**
  Choosing random cartesian coordinates (x,y) and rejecting if outside the disk is fine.
  Choosing random polar coordinates (r, theta) is not acceptable even though r and theta can be assumed uniform, because the distribution in 2D is no longer uniform (even with perfectly uniform r and theta).

If a challenge specifies statistical tests as part of the validity criteria, then that overrides these allowances.

Comment: But if you choose r as `sqrt(x) * (radius of disk)`, where x is uniformly distributed between 0 and 1 (e.g. `(r * math.sqrt(random.random()))`), and with theta between 0 and 2 pi, it is a uniformly random point on a disk.

Comment: `Choosing random cartesian coordinates (x,y) and rejecting if outside the disk is fine.` What does it mean by `rejecting`?

Comment: @KeyuGan this means repeatedly choosing (x,y) randomly, until a pair inside the disk is found.

Comment: I'm surprised that this doesn't mention that, even when uniform is not specified, all values within the range must be possible. [Relevant XKCD](https://xkcd.com/221/)

Comment: @kamil that might be more relevant to the general definition of random ://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1325/20283

Comment: Just say "theoritally same size same probably"?

Comment: Note that sometimes even ‘uniformly random’ is underspecifying. See the Bertrand paradox.

Answer (score 18):

## "input" and "output"

Refer to [Default for Code Golf: Input/Output methods](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods?s=3|1.8774). The list includes, but not is limited to:

- STDIN/STDOUT
- function argument/return value
- command line arguments/program exit code
- reading from/writing to a file
- dialog boxes
- popping from/pushing to the stack (for stack-based languages like GolfScript; this is essentially the equivalent of a function's arguments/return values for those languages)

Comment: I thought the default was "full program required" for code-golf?

Comment: @Jan Yes, it is.

Comment: in which case, point two should probably be clarified as "if a function is requested"

Comment: @JanDvorak Well, by "function" I was referring to a function within a complete program. I shall edit to clarify.

Comment: I'm not clear on the function option "within a complete program". If asked to "square a number", could you write `f=lambda x:x*x`? Would you then need to invoke the function like `f (y)` in addition?

Comment: No command-line args as way of input?

Comment: Maybe add a link to this: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods?s=3|1.8774

Answer (score 16):

## "Black-Box-Functions"

The content (i.e. the code) of black-box-functions may not be accessed, you can only call them (passing arguments if applicable) and observe their output.

They should also have no side effects, except for e.g. accessing RNGs or time, but no communication with the rest of the program should take place other than through the input arguments and the output.

This term is used in the list of default IOs in a number of suggestions. [(1)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13707/24877),[(2)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13713/24877),[(3)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13708/24877)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, idempotence has nothing to do with the definition of *black box functions*.

Comment: Your second paragraph basically describes idempotence...

Comment: Please explain what you mean by *idempotence*. I only know the mathematical meaning of an operation where a function `f` is called *idemptotent* if its composition with itself is itself again, i.e. `f(f(x)) = f(x)` for all `x`, and this certainly does not apply here as far as I understand.

Comment: At least in computer science a function is idempotent if it produces the same results when invoked many times. I suppose this doesn't actually exclude "side effects" depending on your definition. For example an HTTP PUT is supposed to be idempotent because it will always "set" the value to your parameter. However an HTTP POST is not because you're always adding something new.

Comment: Ok I see, but I think the usage of that term in this context is misleading. Usually something like that is called *pure* or *deterministic* but I think the current description is sufficient.

Comment: Okay. I upvoted this before I commented anyway.

Answer (score 11):

## "Positive", "Negative", "Non-Negative", "Non-Positive"

**Positive**, by default, means *strictly* positive, ie. all N larger than zero. Zero is not a positive number.

**Negative** means all N less than zero. Zero is not a negative number.

**Non-negative** means all N larger than *or equal to* zero. Zero *is* a non-negative number.

**Non-Positive** means all N smaller than *or equal to* zero. Zero *is* a non-positive number.

Comment: These are standard mathematical terms, but posting them here is still a good idea. You should add **non-positive** to complete the set.

Comment: Note that some places, such as France, consider positive to include 0, which is why I felt this needed to be included in the standard definitions.

Comment: That's weird. France is silly and wrong

Comment: @JoKing I've heard people in England use them as loanwords: **positif**  = non-negative; **négatif** = non-positive, pronounced [pɒzɪˈtiːf] and [nɛɡəˈtiːf], but this is not mainstream

Comment: As ngn pointed out, this is not mainstream, in France we often use "*positif **ou nul***" to say **non-negative** which is different from "*positif*" alone

Comment: What about "signed" and "unsigned"? They are related to negative-ness.

Comment: What about negative 0 (`-0`)?

Answer (score 6):

## Universally testable answers

An answer will be considered to be universally testable if:

1. It is written in a programming language which has a compiler/interpreter available on Windows, Linux & Mac where said compiler/interpreter can be downloaded from the web free of charge (not including free trials) and does not require sign up/registration.
2. or it is written in a programming language that has an online compiler/interpreter such as http://ideone.com/, which is available free of charge and does not require sign up/registration, where the answer may be fully tested within the online compiler/interpreter i.e. doesn't need access to local resources.

Additionally, if the behaviour of the answer is different on different platforms/architectures, it should still meet the question criteria on all platforms/architectures.

Comment: doesn't this exclude .net and thus C#?

Comment: Mono is an open source implementation (and is available on ideone)

Comment: This also excludes powershell and bash

Comment: This restriction would only apply if a question asker specifies it. This is just to provide the definition. Personally, i would prefer to verify whether an apparently winning answer actually works and meets the question criteria, which is only possible if i can test it.

Comment: @JanDvorak, how does it exclude bash? Cygwin is free to download without registration.

Comment: Well I hope including this doesn't become the default, or there won't be any more Mathematica answers until there's an open source implementation of Wolfram Language. ;)

Comment: That would be unfortunate, however, a question asker should be able to test an answer, otherwise they may not always be able to choose a winner due to not being able to verify it as a valid entry.

Comment: I think answers should be testable, but I don't agree that registration/trial-only should disqualify.

Comment: @JohnDvorak also, there are online bash and powershell interpreters

Answer (score -1):

## Write a function

I propose this as the default for code golf questions that as for a function rather than a full program. I'm sorry if this all seems overly pedantic, but I've seen every single one of these points come up in actual questions and answers, and I'd like to have comprehensive rulings on them available.

I must admit I have a limited knowledge of languages, especially esoteric ones, so I welcome suggestions to make this more accessible to a wide class of languages.

### Specification

1) The code must result in a named function (or analogous execution unit in your language) that fits the specifications.

2) The function, when called by name on its inputs, must evaluate to the desired outputs.

3) There can be code outside the function definition, whose characters are also counted.

4) Calling the function multiple times must produce the right answer each time.

5) Optional additional parameters are acceptable; mandatory additional parameters are not.

### Explanations

The spec is meant to capture the idea that a function, once created, should be usable to transform inputs to outputs in the fashion asked for.

**1) The code must result in a named function (or analogous execution unit in your language) that fits the specifications.**

While in C-style languages, the function is usually created by a function definition, this allows for other methods such as a lambda-expression like `f=lambda x:x*x` or a composition `f=compose(g,h)` or a decoration `f=memoize(f)` as long as the result is saved to a variable.

**2) The function, when called by name on its inputs, must evaluate to the desired outputs.**

This captures the requirement that the function be a function. Its inputs should be passed in, rather than taken through STDIN or taken from a global valuable. Its value must be returned, rather than saved to a variable or printed. To be clear, this does not mean an invocation of the function by included in the code, but that the function must behave as desired in invoked.

**3) There can be code outside the function definition, whose characters are also counted.**

This rule is an assurance that even if asked for a function, your code doesn't entirely have to do that function. Programs might make imports, saved global variable, and define auxiliary functions outside that function.

**4) Calling the function multiple times must produce the right answer each time.**

In other words, it's not acceptable to have your function only work the first time. Subsequent calls within a single run should also work according to the spec. This could come up if the function modifies a global value.

This does not preclude the function modifying the value it was passed in. So, the function `f` should print the same output twice on `print f(1,2); print f(1,2)` but not necessarily `l=[1,2]; print f(l); print f(l)`.

[Here's an answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/36572/20260) where this question can up in practice, with Falko's suggestion to save a character by defining the initial list as an optional parameter `def f(a,b=[0]*1000):` causes it to be overwritten for subsequent runs.

**5) Optional additional parameters are acceptable; mandatory additional parameters are not.**

In other words, if asked for a function that takes two numbers, it's fine to have one that takes two numbers and an optional third number, as long as it behaves as asked when given only two numbers. The reasoning is that this would pass any test according to the specs, so it can behave arbitrarily in the non-spec case of three numbers. However, having a mandatory additional parameter and saying "call `f` as `f(a,b,0)` does not fit the spec.

An optional additional parameter might be useful for golf to define a recursive function or to save a method name to a variable before the function body.

### Things not addressed

**Input/outputs formats:** If asked for a function that takes no numbers, can yours instead take a list/array/tuple of two numbers? Can you output a float if asked for a whole number?

**Fallbacks:** What should a language that does have functions do? I think this should be addressed with a general convention of "Do the closest you can, but only if what was required was impossible in the language.

Comment: Point 1 as written seems to preclude languages which don't have function types. A more language-independent way of phrasing it would be to talk about *names* rather than *variables*.

Comment: Point 3 gets a bit problematic when it talks about imports. An answer which is a program should include imports, but I'm not sure that requirement makes sense for a function (or code snippet) unless you also require that e.g. Java answers to a "*write a function*" questions include a wrapping `class A{}`. Otherwise there's no way to have both imports and a function which makes any syntactic sense.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Could you give me an example of a language that uses names rather than variables so I can look into it?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'm confused -- I intended to make Point 3 exactly to allow things like imports.

Comment: Languages which don't have function types include Java (pre-8, at least; I'm not sure what the implementation details of lambdas are) and PHP. With respect to point 3, what I'm trying to say is that a Java answer which begins `import java.math.BigInteger;BigInteger f(BigInteger x){...` is syntactic nonsense, and I think that if people want to ask for functions rather than full programs then they should give you imports for free.

Comment: Would replacing "variable" with "name" solve the type issue, or is the term "function" itself problematic? Is is standard for Java golfs to allow certain libraries for free? Python golfs would certainly be a lot different if given a free `import itertools as i`.

Comment: The term "function" isn't ideal: some languages don't use the term. But it's not nearly as bad as "variable", which has a defined meaning in nearly every mainstream language and plenty of esoteric ones. If you want to be particularly clear you could say "named function, named verb, named block, or other named execution unit as appropriate to your language".

Comment: As for allowing libraries for free: there is at least [one example](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/928/194) of a Java function golf which doesn't mention its import, but Java function golfs are so rare that I don't think there's much "standard" to talk about. There may be a case to be made that if you're asking people to do a task which is going to require imports then you should ask for a full program, not a function, although predicting which tasks will benefit from imports in which languages isn't easy.

Comment: OK, I broadened the language a bit for function and variable. For the Java issue, do you think there would be support for a rule that `code length = import length + function length` for function questions?

Comment: Consensus seems to be [that functions don't have to be named unless the OP explicitly asks for it](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1503/8478).

Answer (score -6):

## "N random X"

*Where N denotes a natural number and X denotes (members of) a set with finite cardinality.*

The standard definition for "N random X" is "**N independent identically distributed uniform (pseudo-) random samples from the space of all X**".

As a concrete case "generate 3 random printable ASCII characters" could be satisfied by `[1,2,3].map(_=>String.fromCharCode(Math.random()*95+32))` in JavaScript (ES6).

Comment: I am quite willing to work on the wording if anybody has a better suggestion.

Comment: Question http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/100729/56071 asks for "N random printable ASCII characters" and it seems clear from the answers that the common interpretation is the one above, so I think it best to resolve any ambiguities with a standard definition.

Comment: I disagree with having this as a standard definition — instead my opinion is that questions should *always* specify what they mean by *N random X*