# Default for Code Golf: Input/Output methods

Tags: discussion, faq, policy, code-golf, defaults

It looks like [we have a consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419/8478) that we want certain defaults for the format which answers are expected in for [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). On that poll, the question arose twice, which input/output formats should be allowed for programs and functions.

So here is another poll. This one works different though. All the input/output methods are independent of each other, so there will be one answer per method. Upvote all you think are reasonable for the default. Downvote those which you think shouldn't be allowed unless the OP explicitly permits them.

To keep this remotely manageable, I have not posted individual answers for all possible inputs for functions. So there are only four: functions can take input/output via their arguments and return values. Or functions can use any method full programs can. I don't think there is any point in (say) allowing programs to take input from STDIN (only) and to allow functions to take input from ARGV (only) or something like that. If you disagree, please leave a comment.

If I've overlooked an I/O method, feel free to add your own answer.

**Note:** Some votes have been reverted because they were detected as serial voting. If you vote on multiple answers, please leave some time between votes.

A method is allowed if it has 5 net votes and at least twice as many upvotes as downvotes.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4708/34718) (Can numeric input/output be in the form of byte values)

Comment: "The current results of the polls are now part of the tag wiki" which tag wiki? meta wiki has nothing for code-golf tag. ppcg wiki has https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info but it's missing a lot of answers here.

Answer (score 150):

## Functions may output via their return value(s)

Comment: How many languages support this?  I support outputting to STDOUT.

Comment: @hosch250 Wait, are there languages that have functions without return values? o.O

Comment: Oh, that is not considered outputting the last I heard - that is returning a value.  If the question asks for a function, this is correct.  If the question asks for a program, I support outputting to STDOUT or a file.

Comment: @hosch250 This particular answer only concerns functions. *Whether* functions and/or programs are allowed is another question (see the linked meta question, but of course it's ultimately up to the challenge author). But this answers says that *if* functions are allowed, then they should be allowed to use their return value for the result - as are all other answers here that start with the word `Functions`.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I definitely will vote on this then.

Comment: @MartinEnder Most (all?) 8-bit BASIC interpreters do not specifically return a value from a sub-routine, whilst many will allow you to define a mathematical function with the `DEF` keyword, this is quite limited. I also don't recall Amiga BASIC included with WorkBench having return values from sub-routines but it's been many years since I did any Amiga BASIC so don't quote me on that. 6502/10 assembly does not return values from sub-routines either. If you know that you've stored your result in the accumulator, then you simply use that on return from your sub-routine.

Comment: @MartinEnder Yes, scratch has no return values for it's functions

Comment: @Hosch250 There are languages that don't have STDOUT, like JS

Comment: @VFDan In case of JS, `console.log`-ing is often regerded as STDOUT. Also, Node.js **does** have a STDOUT.

Answer (score 131):

## Functions may take input via function arguments

Comment: I use this in a lot of my questions, so definitely.

Comment: Can it take array via repeatedly call a function, once a value?

Comment: @l4m2 that sounds like a special form of currying and would be worth asking about in a separate question. (In principle, this should be valid, but it's worth discussing explicitly.)

Answer (score 129):

## Programs may take input via STDIN

Answer (score 123):

## Programs may output to STDOUT

Answer (score 106):

## Programs may take input via GUI prompts

(This is for languages, for which this is the closest alternative to STDIN, like JavaScript's `prompt()`, Mathematica's `Input[]` or `InputString[]`, Matlab's `input()` and VBScript's `InputBox()`.)

Comment: What about for other languages?

Comment: @Ypnypn I'm not aware of a language which can read from STDIN, but where producing a graphical prompt is shorter than that. But in that case, I'd say either is fine.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Matlabs `input('')` usually just reads from the command line, perhaps you mean `inputdlg('')`?

Comment: Anyway, Mma's `Input` and `InputString` both take the next line of input when run in a script.

Comment: @MartinEnder `wscript`.

Comment: Bash `read <var>`

Comment: So reading choice from `confirm` and `msgbox` etc. are also allowed

Answer (score 100):

## Programs may output by displaying it on screen.

This makes it possible to use languages like *Vim script* that can't print output directly to *stdout*.

Example from [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/59464/print-like-this) challenge:

```
$ echo "This is a test line!" | vim - -c 'nm Q vEUWvEuWQ|norm Q'
```

Will display:

```
THIS is A test LINE!
~
~
~
~
~
```

Within a *Vim* session.

I think that this way of displaying the result should be valid. I am sure that there are other domain specific languages like *Vim script* that lacks full I/O support and could use another way to display the result.

Comment: Incidentally, vim's output is standard output, but if you processed standard output, there is extra garbage there.

Comment: It's not even just domain specific languages. I'd say QBasic falls in this category: it doesn't have any concept of an output (or input) stream, but rather writes characters to a "window."

Answer (score 94):

## Programs may output using their exit code...

Exit codes are basically a return value for programs. If functions can output using their return values, it makes sense that programs should be able to do the same.

Examples:

- [Java exit codes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/457338/3224483)
- [C and C++ exit codes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/3224483)

Comment: Hmm…should this perhaps be "if and only if the challenge requires as output an integer whose value is guaranteed to be between 0 and 255, inclusive"? For example, if the challenge is "output the number of arguments passed to the program," then `int main(int argc, char **argv) { return argc; }` should _not_ be a valid solution (IMO), because the exit code is masked by `0xFF`. (Perhaps this is implicit in the rule as a part of correctness? Just want to be clear.)

Comment: @wchargin That seems like a limitation of whatever you are using to run your program. I can write a PowerShell script like `exit 1000000`, and execute it in PowerShell ISE. [This gives me no problems.](http://i.imgur.com/eH5llLa.png)

Comment: Interesting—I didn't know that. As far as I know, this is true on all *nix OSes (including Mac), but I'd be happy to be corrected!

Comment: is there a reason to limit this to integers? i mean if there's an environment where  a program can return something other than an integer  why not allow that too?

Comment: @Jasen I don't see a reason to limit it to integers.

Comment: I'm new to this site. Would a crashed program's exit code considered a valid way of output (for example, `SIGSEGV`)?

Comment: @ShmuelH. If you intentionally crash a program (or just use the equivalent of `exit(code)` in that language) to get a specific exit code, it's valid.

Answer (score 85):

## Programs may take input via command-line arguments

Answer (score 82):

## Functions may take multiple arguments via [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)

For some functional programming languages like Haskell this is actually necessary, because only single-argument functions exist and functions with multiple arguments are (somewhat transparently) implemented as curried functions. (The alternative would be to take a list or tuple of the values, but that is not how one would naturally write a two-argument function in Haskell.)

[As per this consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8425/8478) the same should also be allowable for languages where multi-argument functions do exist. As an example from JavaScript, instead of defining

```
f=(a,b)=>...
```

and calling it like `f(a,b)` one could then also define

```
f=a=>b=>...
```

and call it like `f(a)(b)`.

Answer (score 79):

## The contents of the tape post-execution may be used as a Turing machine's output

Comment: This has my upvote.

Comment: Emphasis on the "post-execution". If you allow the final tape of a non-halting turing machine to be considered out, your program can calculate a non-computable function.

Answer (score 68):

## Functions may output via the same methods as full programs

(This depends on how the poll goes, but could be any subset of STDOUT, STDERR and file.)

Comment: This violates the single-responsibility principle, the separation of concerns principle, and I don't think it's really useful in code golf. Moreover, functional programming languages won't let you do that at all, and I want some more love for Haskell.

Comment: @JanDvorak One simple golf use is that `print` is shorter than `return` in Python.

Comment: Eugh. Not a fan of that optimisation. What it could be useful for is printing in a loop rather than collecting results in an array. Still not a fan of allowing that.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yeesh, I did not consider that one could print repeatedly to "output" a list. I think that should not be allowed even if this vote passes because the output is not the list that is asked for.

Comment: @xnor Why not, full programs are allowed to do that, too, right?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Hmm, you're right, what a program really "outputs" is the string representation of the result, so this rule should mean functions can too for consistency. But this is another awkward consequence that makes me disfavor this rule.

Comment: what about exit codes? aren't functions suposed to be reusable? if my function exits the program it isn't reusable. that's what the title indicates

Answer (score 64):

## Programs may output to STDERR

Comment: Can anyone give a comment as to why not to? For example, `print("Hello, world!")` in lua prints to STDERR.

Comment: Forbidding output to STDERR seems incompatible with allowing [output to the screen](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7139).

Comment: This should go as standar... Ah. I see.

Comment: The only problem I see with this is vagueness between what is written to STDERR by the "language" and what is written by the "program." If a distinction between those is not made, this would permit error quines and answers like [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/17288/61384), which is questionably valid.

Comment: I think this shouldn't be allowed by default (but could be explicitly allowed on some challenges). I believe this goes against the spirit of some challenges such as [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107964/output-programming-language-name). On the other hand it could be explicitly forbidden but not everybody will think of this

Comment: This is game-breaking for PHP, where `<?=a;` outputs `a` to STDOUT and `Notice:  Use of undefined constant a - assumed 'a' in [...][...] on line 3` to STDERR.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel This means that outputting to STDERR only counts if that's your chosen output format.

Comment: @YoYoYonnY Since when? All Lua 5.1-5.3 output to stdout…

Answer (score 63):

## Functions may output by modifying their arguments or writing to out arguments

Here, "out arguments" refers to arguments that are passed in by reference, so that modifying the *value* inside the function (as opposed to just overwriting the argument) also modifies the value outside the function (otherwise, the output value would not be observable after the function returns). Note that this is not possible in all languages with all types.

Comment: Does this mean that in languages that allow it, the seven characters for `return ` can simply be replaced with an assignment?

Comment: @ThomasKwa Yes, provided the changed value will then be accessible in the context that called the function.

Comment: so you mean this is only legal in languages that have out arguments, pass by reference, or some similar semantic?  for instance not in shell...

Comment: @Jasen I don't know about shell, but yes to your question.

Comment: This should be clarified to say that you have to actually modify the argument, not just overwrite it. See [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128782/20080) for an incorrect use.

Comment: @isaacg Good point, thank you.

Comment: @isaacg you need to link to a specific revision for that comment to make sense.

Comment: The revision that I referred to about is https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/128782/6

Answer (score 58):

## For stack-based languages, function's input may be pushed to the stack before calling

Stack-based languages may assume that the input for their function is automatically pushed to the stack.

Comment: +1, this is the de facto standard for CJam and GolfScript (and probably some other stack-based languages). You might want to make a corresponding answer for output.

Comment: I think the emphasis here needs to be on "function", as opposed to snippet. There's a very fine line between the two...

Comment: Are there any stack based langauges that let you define functions? As far as I am aware most of them do not and do only let you write *full programs* with IO via STDIO. (in my opinion *functions* should satisfy (perhaps among other criterions): pieces of code that can be reused in the same program, without typing them out again)

Comment: @flawr Vitsy has functions, in some aspects. There are a few stack-based languages that have scope, but I can't name them immediately.

Comment: @flawr for completion sake: lots (most?) of non-esoteric stack-based languages let you define functions. Factor, Forth, Postscript, Joy, Cat, and many others all have functions (both named and anonymous). dc (the RPN calculator) has registers that can work like functions.

Comment: @flawr: Underload lets you reuse the functions in question (in a kind-of awkward way, as Underload has no method of naming things, but it's possible and fairly common).

Comment: Would this apply to a language that has explicit but no implicit IO?

Answer (score 55):

## Programs may output to a file

Comment: Why are people against this?

Comment: @xnor is `/dev/null` considered a valid output file? I might as well submit a blank program and claim it outputs the correct answer to `/dev/null`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts No, `/dev/null` is not a valid output file, for the exact reason that the output cannot be examined later. "Output to a file" means that you can see the program's output by viewing a particular file.

Comment: using strace (or chroot, or mv!)  you can see what was written to /dev/null

Comment: @PatrickRoberts But it doesn't output to `/dev/null`

Answer (score 55):

## Functions may take input via the same methods as full programs

(This depends on how the poll goes, but could be any subset of STDIN, ARGV and file.)

Comment: This violates the single-responsibility principle, the separation of concerns principle, and I don't think it's really useful in code golf. Moreover, functional programming languages won't let you do that at all, and I want some more love for Haskell.

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't see the relevance of good coding practices for code golf. And some languages don't even *have* functions and they aren't necessarily at a disadvantage by allowing functions. The idea of being more liberal in the options for I/O is so that each language can pick what's really shortest.

Comment: The only time that I would object to a function taking input in the same way as a program is if the question was phrased "Write a function that takes the following arguments". This poll applies to questions that are not in such a specific format, so I see no reason to exclude functions that read from stdin.

Comment: @MartinBüttner noted. I still don't like this option, but feel free to override my preferences. The vote split is very close to the threshold ATM.

Answer (score 53):

## Programs may combine two or more input methods

For example, if the inputs are a string and an int, a function that takes a string as an argument and an int from STDIN would be valid.

The input format must still be consistent for a given program.

Answer (score 52):

## Input may be entirely ignored

If a challenge specifies that your program should take a certain selection of inputs, but not all of them are necessary for you to solve the task, you can simply not take the ones you don't need. (This is equivalent to taking them via a method that your language doesn't look at, such as via command-line argument in a language which has no access to the command line arguments.)

Comment: Are you implying that if the challenge was "take three numbers as input a, b, and c, and return a+b", then `print(input()+input())` would be a valid Python submission?

Comment: @Challenger5: Right. Also that that would be a valid submission if the request was to return a+c. (Even without this, you could still do that by saying, for example, "a and c are input via standard input, and b from a file". This rule's basically meant to avoid the absurdity of having to do that.)

Answer (score 51):

## Where applicable, Turing machines supporting multiple halt states may also output via their halt state

This is essentially equivalent to programs outputting via their exit code.

Comment: This has my upvote.

Comment: Turing Machines as I've seen them defined leave output on their tape and have a single halt state. Is there some precedent for what you are suggesting?

Comment: @xnor: That is usually the case, but I have seen dialects of turing machine code that do support multiple halt states. (For example, in the morphett.info dialect that I usually use, `halt` is the basic halt state, but any state of the form `halt-<any string>` is also treated as a halt state.)

Answer (score 50):

## Input for Turing machines may be written to the tape pre-execution

The read-write head should start on the leftmost cell of the portion of the tape containing the input.

Comment: This has my upvote.

Comment: I think this should only be allowed if that's the only method of input.

Comment: For standard turing machines, it is.

Comment: What happened here, SuperJedi? You posted an answer, then commented "This has my upvote" an hour later?

Comment: @MDXF At the time, several other answers on this question had comments like that added by their authors (including many of Martin's answers). At least one was instead commented "This has my downvote." Basically, it was intended as a way to vote on your own meta proposals because you can't actually upvote or downvote your own answers on this site. Interestingly, most of those comments on this topic seem to have since been removed.

Comment: @SuperJedi224 Ah, okay, thanks. I was suspecting sock action, but that makes sense.

Answer (score 41):

## SQL submissions may take input from a named table

which is probably not good enough. But I don't know a better way.

Comment: Should be OK, as long as that input is treated as data, not executable code

Answer (score 41):

## Functions may return a list via acting as a generator

In other words, writing a function to return list elements lazily on request, using support that the language already has for doing that, is allowed (currently it's frequently seen but something of a gray area). This would be idiomatic in most of the languages which have it.

Comment: I wasn't aware this was even a point of contention...

Comment: I don't think it is, but we don't have it listed, and converting a generator to a list is fairly expensive byte-wise in Prolog (there's a builtin for it but it has a fairly long name). So I wanted to confirm that I don't have to do the conversion in my Prolog answers.

Comment: Some things in Python 2 return a list, but in Python 3 it return a generator. Like `range`.

Comment: @mbomb007 I think Python 3s `range` is equivalent to Python 2s `xrange` and Python 2s `range` is something different...

Comment: Basically. Python 2's `range` is like calling `list()` on the result.

Comment: Maybe not in fastest code…

Answer (score 40):

## Programs may take input as the value of the last expression

Using something like TI-84 BASIC's `Ans`, which is a variable that stores the value of the last expression. This the shortest way for TI-BASIC to take input, but its validity was [recently questioned](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/73977/29750). To be clear, this is how the process works with `Ans`:

- Within a program, type the input (number, list, string, etc.), followed by a newline to separate statements, followed by the program name, then press Enter. For example,

  ```
  1337
  prgmFACTOR
  ```
- Outside a program, type the input, press Enter, then type the program name and press Enter.

Edit: I came across a way of using `Ans` that is similar to command-line arguments, which are [allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2449/29750): All as one expression, type the input, followed by a colon, followed by `pgrmNAMEHERE`. For example, `1337:pgrmFACTOR`.

Comment: I think by definition that submission would not be a full program but a snippet that requires some sort of REPL environment which are disallowed by default.

Comment: I think that TI-BASIC is a special case, it being fundamentally different from other languages, and only being callable _from_ what can be considered a REPL; so what then is to differ a full program from a snippet?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I disagree, you can write full programs in the *REPL* but you can *also* write them in separate "files" that can be executed. They even support arguments when the program is called, but can also read from stdin or via prompt.

Comment: @flawr On the 84+ series they can't take arguments, and there's no STDIN, only a prompt.

Comment: @lirtosiast According to the official TI 84+ guidebook both commands `Input` and `Prompt` are available. Both let the program fetch user input. Both behave alot like e.g. `input()` in Python or MATLAB.

Comment: @flawr I agree about their similarity; what I meant is that they display a `?` that prompts the user to type something.

Comment: @lirtosiast Is that an issue? I think many languages do have symbols to denote new inputs/new lines.

Comment: @flawr It's not an issue.

Comment: @flawr It's worth noting that you can't write full programs in the REPL, at least for the TI-83 and -84 calculators. For example, the `Input`/`Prompt` and looping commands can't be used from the REPL.

Comment: Does this mean using `_` for the Python REPL is valid?

Comment: @JakobCornell There are actually assembly programs that let you bypass that

Answer (score 39):

## Assembly programs may take input from registers

If there are no I/O devices available, an answer might consist of a subroutine that reads its input values from the machine registers.

Comment: There's potential for abuse. What if someone creates a machine with a million different special-purpose registers?

Comment: @lirtosiast Good for code colf then. I don't see how that's different from golfing languages with prefilled vars

Comment: @lirtosiast I believe the programming language used has to be defined before the challenge starts.

Comment: If you golf with x86-64, the standard calling conventions already pass args in registers.  So you can just write a normal function that's callable from compiler-generated code.

Comment: This needs clarification: can we use *any* register, or only the ones that would be specified to be used by the ABI?

Comment: Update on calling conventions: you don't *have* to use a standard C calling convention.  Your language is assembly / machine code, so presumably that's the caller's language as well.  They can pass args and take return value(s) in any registers including FLAGS on machines with condition codes, as discussed in [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165020)

Answer (score 36):

### Functions in stack-based languages can leave the output on the stack

Mostly for completeness sake. This is the de-facto standard for CJam and GolfScript and probably other stack-based languages.

Comment: This is also how Forth works.

Comment: Would this apply to a language that has explicit but no implicit IO?

Comment: @Zacharý not sure what you mean?

Comment: A language like Befunge or something similar. Or am I misunderstanding the concept of "function" in these kinds of languages?

Comment: @Zacharý Befunge doesn't have functions so this answer doesn't apply.

Comment: I disagree. I think they can leave it on the stack if implicit output is available. There is no way to check if it's left on the stack otherwise.

Comment: @MDXF Wouldn't that be equivalent to allowing functions in "normal" languages only to use their return value, if the language has implicit output for return values, otherwise there's no way to check if the return value actually has the correct output?

Comment: Yeah, like BIT++

Answer (score 35):

## Assembly programs may write output to some specified memory location

If there are no I/O devices available, an answer might consist of a subroutine that writes its output values to some specified memory location (e.g. write a machine word to `$0000`).

Comment: I think this includes writing to a buffer for outputting multiple values.

Comment: I feel like all these similar posts could be combined into something like "Programs may use registers/variables/memory locations for input/output if no input/output device is available". That would cover assembly programs as well as SQL and other higher level languages with the same problems.

Answer (score 35):

## Functions may return a boolean value via the presence or absence of an error/exception

That is, crashing to return `false`, and not crashing to return `true`. This is the function equivalent of outputting via exit code, which is allowed for full programs (nearly all interpreters will return an exit code of 0 by default if the program doesn't crash, and nonzero if it does).

I realised this wasn't on the list while writing a post about how our I/O defaults applied to Brachylog; this method of outputting booleans is idiomatic in most declarative languages (i.e. it's something I'd be likely to write even if I *weren't* golfing), and it's still meaningful in other paradigms (much rarer, but it's nonetheless considered an acceptable programming technique in industry in languages like OCaml).

I'm not completely convinced either way about whether this should be accepted, although I'm currently mildly in favour (the main point in favour is that it's often the most natural way to do output even if you aren't golfing, and many languages have a `try`/`catch` or equivalent to convert it into a regular Boolean; the main point against is that it feels a bit cheap/abusable). However, we could definitely do with a ruling as to whether this is acceptable or not, as there are many cases in which it's going to be the shortest way to write the code, and thus it matters for how [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) answers are written.

Comment: This is pretty much "output via exit code" for functions. +1 from me.

Comment: Not sure about this either way, but it would be a significant change for Python golfing. Especially so if a recursive function that keeps nesting is considered a stack overflow error, which is a bit weird since it's common to assume there's unlimited stack depth.

Comment: If anything, I think this should only be allowed in languages with some way of handling errors (usually try/catch). Otherwise, it would be impossible to actually use the code in a program.

Comment: @12Me21 I read "crash" as different to "error" or "exception", where "crash" is always non-recoverable.

Comment: Is there a contradiction here with our stance on function reusability, namely [Do function submissions have to be reusable?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4940/92901) and [Should submissions be allowed to exit with an error?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4781/92901)

Comment: More recent meta discussion that expands on my comment above: [Functions throwing exceptions: an exception to the rules?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24526/92901)

Answer (score 33):

### Input and output of a single value may be represented as a singleton list

For example, if the value was `4`, `[4]` would be an acceptable representation (using Python list syntax).

Comment: This is useful in array languages like J.

Answer (score 32):

## In languages without any method of input (e.g. ///) programs may get input through an insertion into the source code

Comment: @DLosc What about code in /// that requires changing at the end? E.g. a simple program that adds a full stop to the end of a string if there isn't already a full stop there `/.;/;//x///;/.x;/(input goes here);` where `x` is a special character (maybe a newline) that is guaranteed not to be in the input.

Comment: This is called hard coding.

Comment: @boboquack Can we allow hard-coded input in languages that support input commands?

Comment: That's a good question, and from experience I would guess no, but you should search on meta/ask your own question here. @A_

Comment: Does this include 2d programming languages and/or cellular automata?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms It's been a long time since I've thought about this, but I would assume yes.

Comment: @boboquack I'm going to post a separate set of answers, as it seems different enough the consensus may differ. Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 31):

## Submissions may use list of strings instead of multi-line strings

Input or output may be the equivalent of the string separated by newlines. For example, the multiline string:

```
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
```

May be instead be taken as a list of strings like:

```
["1","2","Fizz","4","Buzz"]
```

Comment: I always see comments about this in multiline challenges, so I thought I'd throw this up there and see if it is well-recieved as a standard form of input

Comment: I would add an exception for [tag:ascii-art] as linebreaks can be an important part of those challenges.

Answer (score 29):

## Assembly programs may read input from some specified memory location

If there are no I/O devices available, an answer might consist of a subroutine that reads its input values from some specified memory location (e.g. read a zero-terminated string starting at `$0000`).

Comment: This would be natural for various 8-bit micros.

Comment: and for ms-dos where the command-line is at 80h

Comment: Seems pretty cheesy for normal x86/x86-64 code.  I could use a register as an index into one input, and as a pointer to another input array that started at address `0`.  (`xor edx,edx`, `mov eax, [rsi+rdx]`, `add eax, [rdx]`).  I think it's a lot more reasonable to assume pointers to input/output arrays in registers of your choice (even if the standard calling convention uses stack args), except for things like 8-bit micros.

Answer (score 27):

## Full programs may take array/string input (of unknown length) via stdin in the form of `<length> <contents>` or `<contents> <sentinel>`

EOF handling is a common problem in many languages, not just esolangs. But only "regular" languages that support proper arrays and functions can circumvent this issue by writing functions instead of full programs.

Most programming contest problems (which only support stdin/stdout as I/O) solve this issue by giving extra information in the standard input in one of the two ways:

- give "how many items you need to expect in the input" in the standard input itself, before the start of the actual content, or
- give a special value at the end of input so that you can "terminate the program when this value is entered".

I believe these solutions are also a natural extension of

- [An array may be represented in input as a pointer and length](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13262/78410) and
- [An array may be represented as a buffer terminated with a sentinel value](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20871/78410)

to full programs respectively, which currently only apply to functions.

The same condition for the sentinel value applies when the sentinel value method is used:

> It should be noted that the sentinel value must be the one that is guaranteed to not appear in any valid input [...], since their presence breaks the premise of the I/O method.

Answer (score 26):

## Functions may return their result in an optional type wrapper

[Relevant meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14199/61384).

By "optional type wrapper" I mean something like `Maybe a` in Haskell, `Option<T>` in Rust, etc.

The consensus was that this should be allowed because it functions like a singleton wrapper, or like a possibly-erroring function that never actually errors.

Answer (score 25):

## An array may be represented in input as a pointer and length.

For example in C you could use:

```
int f(int*p,int l){...}
```

Comment: Do you think it should be restricted to C?

Comment: @KeyuGan I think it should be allowed in any language with pointers (c++, asm ...). Do you know of a language where this would be a problem?

Comment: I don't know whether a language exists where both pointer and array are well-defined. Under such circumstances, it may benefit a lot from this rule. I would still suggest languages which *does not regard an array of general type as a first-class object* may use a reference to first element and length to replace with array/list inputs.

Comment: I'd say this should only be for a language where this is the natural representation of an array

Comment: @keyugan C# supports both standard arrays and C-style pointers

Comment: @Pavel It is the same situation with C++. As for C# (I'm not an expert), many answers are based on LINQ and seemingly they cannot be shortened in this way. Besides, I will say yes to use pointer / length encapsule here. I think it will be better if we could give some restrictions on what language could do so, according to meta discussion, while the original answer doesn't. https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13210/list-input-in-c-and-length-argument

Comment: @KeyuGan It's just a technicallity really, the only concievable reason to use pointer types in C# is for interop with native code. It probably won't ever apply.

Comment: @KeyuGan Please don't make drastic changes to suggestions.

Comment: How does it affect golfing? It is pretty much the standard way to handle arrays in C. Is the pointer-length pair in the arguments not included in the program length?

Comment: @Alex This establishes that it is an allowable way of taking input in C, or any other pointer based language. Otherwise, it would be nearly impossible for C to take a list as input.

Answer (score 25):

## I/O for [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) questions may either be 0-indexed or 1-indexed

Any [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) question that has the user output the \$n\$th term, first \$n\$ terms, etc. of a sequence should allow programs to index the first element of the sequence as 0 or 1 at the answerer's choice, as long as the program is consistent.

Comment: This is now allowed by the sequence tag default.

Answer (score 24):

## Assembly programs may write output to registers

If there are no I/O devices available, an answer might consist of a subroutine that leaves its computed output values in the machine registers upon returning.

Comment: Most calling conventions return integer values in a register, so this is eminently sensible for code fragments and functions.

Comment: This needs clarification: can we use *any* register, or only the ones that would be specified to be used by the ABI?

Comment: This answer is A, yours is B.

Comment: @user62131: in real-life hand-written assembly language, you do sometimes write helper functions with a totally custom calling convention that return multiple values in registers that are convenient.  i.e. in asm and machine-code answers, you can invent any reasonable calling convention for your function.  See my calling-convention answer on [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165020)

Answer (score 23):

## Multiple arguments to a function can be taken as a list or tuple instead

For example, if you needed to take in two integers as arguments, you can take one argument: a list of both integers.

[Apparently](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/259881/the-jaccard-index#comment572502_259881), this isn't already here, so I'm posting this answer.

Comment: I totally agree.

Comment: What about the opposite? When the challenge has a fixed-length array as input, can we use a function with 5 arguments?

Comment: I think that should be allowed as well…I mean, it makes sense.

Answer (score 22):

## Regexes may output via the list of matched strings (the captured group 0)

Comment: We now have Retina for regex so this can

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Retina is actually Turing Complete.

Comment: ...I'm confused.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline: Retina is more powerful than plain regex is, due to the way it redefined the backquote character (which just matches itself literally in most regex syntaxes). That's enough to [make it Turing complete](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110723/62131).

Comment: True. But Retina is basically regex+. Do we need this anymore?

Comment: I don't think using plain regex is even allowed, since it isn't Turing complete.

Answer (score 21):

## CGI scripts may take input via GET/POST parameters

A CGI script required to take, e.g., three inputs can be expected to be called as the GET request

```
GET script.cgi?<A>=<1st input>&<B>=<2nd input>&<C>=<3rd input> HTTP/1.1
```

(where `A`, `B` and `C` are keys of the poster's choice) of the equivalent POST request.

Comment: Also, PHP<5.4.0 (exclude) has the directive [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) (enabled by default up to PHP4.1), which allows you to use POST, GET, COOKIE, SESSION and what-not. It creates the variables with the names of the keys (E.g.: `a.php?a=1` would create `$_GET[a]` (version-dependent) and the variable `$a` with value `1`). This was removed due to security reasons, but was a standard feature that was (fortunally) removed.

Comment: Also, would `parse_str($_SERVER[QUERY_STRING])` be a valid input method? It does exactly the same as `register_globals`, but reads input parameters from a superglobal and parse them into variables. This is explained in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: This proposed a specific input method. What language features you use to access that input is up to you.

Comment: Then using `$_GET` (superglobal with all GET parameters, in PHP) fits the `"What language features you use to access that input is up to you"`, right?

Comment: Yes, it does, assuming a GET request becomes an accepted input input.

Comment: Then there is the program `<?php eval(key($_GET));`. (SQL table input may have similar problems.)

Comment: @jimmy23013 PHP4.1: `<?eval($c);` (assuming `short_tags` and `register_globals`, the code can be anywhere, even in a cookie (if below 4kb)). Or even `<?eval(fgets(STDIN))`. Or, for Javascript, `eval(prompt())`. Or `eval "$s"` for bash. Other languages have the same problem. Any language that allows evaluation of a string containing code has the same problem

Comment: @Dennis Would ``eval(`return {${location.hash}}`)``, assuming your URL is `http://example.com/#a:"value",other:"value"`, fit in this definition?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel As written, no. Those are neither GET nor POST parameters.

Comment: @Dennis What about `eval(location.search.replace(/^\?/,''))`? It would create every single variable you would need, right away (if the input is numeric and not an array). The `location.search` will contain all the GET parameters, optionally starting with an `?`.

Comment: This can also be done with `php -r '<code>' <A>=<input1> <B>=<input2>` (or `php-cli`, depending on your distribution/installation), which alleviates the need for a web server (a much better option IMO). In this case, scoring is much easier: the `-r` flag would cost 2 bytes, but the ability to drop the leading `<?` in the code balances it out. Each GET parameter would cost 1 byte (for the `=`) plus the length of the parameter name.

Comment: @Mego The `-r` is free. Read: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2424/14732

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Fair enough. The rest of my comment still stands.

Comment: @Mego It's still under discussion.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Hence why I offered my opinion

Comment: this seems like a special case of allowing input via files, stdin, and enviroment variables,

Answer (score 21):

## [black-box functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13706/24877) to be taken as input can be passed as an argument

This holds for functional languages or languanges that do have first class functions/anonymous functions/lambda functions or function pointers, for instance: Java, JavaScript, C++, TI-Basic, Python, Octave, Matlab, Haskell, Lisp

Comment: Huh? I'm confused what makes this different from passing inputs as arguments in general.

Comment: @SolomonUcko You mean as opposed to other non-function input types? In that case nothing, but this should just serve as an additional clarification as we introduced black-box functions just last year into our rules. Also consider these two entries: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13713/24877 https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13707/24877

Answer (score 19):

## Programs may take input from a file

Comment: ... only if makes sense for the challenge, and even then you should input a file name first... I'd say

Comment: @JanDvorak That's a "no", because that makes the file name itself the input (which you would take from STDIN or ARGV).

Answer (score 19):

## Functions may return a function that returns the result

This is very similar to [currying](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8427), the only difference being that only the first call includes an argument. Sometimes it's useful to curry a recursive function that has only one argument, especially if that argument doesn't need to be modified to find the result. For example, each of these JavaScript functions returns the bit-length of a positive integer:

```
f=(n,x)=>n?f(n>>1,-~x):x
f=(n,x)=>n>>x?f(n,-~x):x
n=>f=x=>n>>x?f(-~x):x
```

All three functions can be called by assigning them to `g` and calling them with e.g. `g(49)`; however, the third version must be called again with `g(49)()` to actually return the result. Again, this is very similar to currying, where the arguments are passed separately (`g(a)(b)` rather than `g(a,b)`).

Note that no additional input should be needed to get the result (i.e. "to call on a number `x`, use `f(x)(2)`"). Optional arguments are fine, of course (`x=>(y=2)=>x+y`).

There is also a meta post about this [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11153/42545), though it was closed as a duplicate of this question.

Comment: The only restriction I'd like to see on this is that no additional input should be needed to fetch the result. In other words, the returned function should take no mandatory arguments (optional arguments are fine), so that `f(whatever)()` would return the result. Otherwise, it falls under additional unspecified input, and therefore violates that loophole.

Comment: @Mego Thanks, I agree. I thought that was implicit, but I've added a mention to the post.

Comment: How many brackets at the last is allowed? 1? or allowed if not that large(only avoid loophole)

Comment: @l4m2 I'm only vouching for one extra function call here; you could write another answer allowing multiple extraneous calls if you wish.

Comment: @l4m2, I thought about any constant (not related to input) number.

Answer (score 19):

## Programs and functions may return a boolean value via the presence or absence of output

Comment: This is for decision-problem formats, I presume.

Comment: @Giuseppe Yep. Modeled it after the [similar one for errors](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11908/73884).

Answer (score 19):

### You may assume that the input is valid

When parsing an input, you may assume that the input is already valid. You are not required to validate it unless the challenge is specifically about testing whether the input is valid or not.

Answer (score 17):

## When a challenge asks for an array as input/output, you may use a list instead, and vice-versa

Note that some languages may lack one of these concepts. For example, **TI-Basic** does not have an array datatype (but has lists) and **C** does not have a list in its standard library, but has arrays as part of the language.

In keeping with the general flexibility of I/O formats, I suggest we allow to use them interchangeably for all languages.

Comment: A [fairly recent](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16528/71434) meta discussion which basically reached the conclusion that saying "list" in a challenge description is equivalent to any number of possible implementations in different languages which may or may not have different names. To put it a different way, I agree with your intention but I don't think it needs to be specified that "different languages use different words for fundamentally equivalent concepts".

Answer (score 16):

## Regexes may output via any captured groups

Users can specify which subset of captured group(s) contains the output; it doesn't have to be just group 0.

Comment: perhaps reword to "a specified subset of captured groups" any could be mis-interpreted as allowing a different subset at each call.

Comment: Is this to be interpreted such that the specification of which backref(s) contain the output is not counted towards the byte length of the regex program? I would strongly disagree with that, since the backref numbers are an integral part of the program and without them, it would not do anything useful. Is there any other language with a rule like this? At best, any regex answer that uses this rule should be treated as a distinct language which varies depending on the exact combination of backref numbers, [like command-line parameters](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/17216).

Comment: @Deadcode yes, there are other languages with rules like this: [asm may output via registers](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8509/6484), and specifying the register numbers doesn't add to your byte count.

Comment: Should non-participating capture groups count as empty string / 0 for the purpose of this rule?

Comment: Also, for unary regexes, can the meaning of the capture groups be specified to include combinations of groups to make output of larger numbers possible, for example `\4`*`\2`^2 + `\5`*`\2` + `\6` or [examples such as those shown here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17424/17216)? Without this, it is only possible to output numbers less than or equal to the input (or the largest input number, in the case of multiple delimited input numbers).

Answer (score 16):

## Functions may return a promise containing the output

### About Promises

- [Wikipedia article on futures & promises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises)
- [MDN article on the JavaScript `Promise` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

---

### Example

Consider the following function to retrieve my rep from the API, with the output logged from the last `Promise` in the chain:

```js
f=

_=>fetch("//api.stackexchange.com/users/58974?site=codegolf").then(r=>r.json()).then(j=>console.log(j.items[0].reputation))

f()
```

I propose instead that we simply be allowed to return the `Promise` containing the output, like so:

```js
f=

_=>fetch("//api.stackexchange.com/users/58974?site=codegolf").then(r=>r.json()).then(j=>j.items[0].reputation)

f().then(console.log)
```

---

### Conditions of Use

> This section requires more detail, please edit it to include any other conditions you think should be covered or to add tags to the existing conditions.

#### [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

In challenges that use code length as a measure for the winning criterion, returning a promise would not be permitted if further manipulation would be required to achieve the desired output, as in this example:

```js
f=

_=>fetch("//api.stackexchange.com/users/58974?site=codegolf").then(r=>r.json()).then(j=>j.items[0])

f().then(i=>console.log(i.reputation))
```

#### [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)

If this method is used in time-based challenges then the time required to resolve the final promise *must* be counted towards your score.

Comment: I feel like we should allow it but add a penality of 5 bytes (`.then`) due to the overhead in calling like using a command line flag.

Comment: @Christoph, I can see your point. I suggest posting that as a counter-proposal as simply editing in as an option above won't tell us what the consensus is.

Comment: I'd allow this except in [tag:fastest-code] and similar time-based challenges (or at least count the time taken in forcing the promise, in that case), for what I hope are obvious reasons.

Comment: @ais523, I've added a section on conditions of use, feel free to edit it to add more detail, tags and/or examples.

Comment: This should be updated for `await` / `async` - especially as Chrome console has top-level await. The "get the answer" part of the [code-golf] snippet can be shortened to `(await f()).reputation`.

Answer (score 16):

## [black-box functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13706/24877) to be taken as input can be assumed to be predefined under a given name

This holds for languages that do have classical functions, for instance: Java, JavaScript, VB, C, C++, TI-Basic (some versions), Python, Octave, Matlab, Haskell, Lisp

This proposition is the opposite of [that one](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13713/24877) which only allows this method of taking input for languages that cannot take functions as arguments.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what is meant by this, but if I interpret it correctly, this will have my downvote, as inputs are never assumed to be stored in a variable already, so why are functions any different?

Comment: @Sanchises The problem is a lack of other ways for some languages. E.g. before Java introduced lambdas recently (so everything before Java 8), there was no way for a function to take a "functional" input.

Comment: Maybe add this method as an exception to the other one, so only when your language does not have function pointers or similar?

Comment: @Sanchises I now added a second proposal that includes your suggestion, see linked.

Answer (score 16):

## Lists of decimal digits and strings that match `^[0-9]*$` are interchangeable...

...but not when this may make the input format inconsistent.

For example, let's say you can assume the string input will match `^[1457]+$`, which is a subset of `^[0-9]*$`. Then, `'1775'` can also be input as `[1, 7, 7, 5]`.

However, for a counterexample, let's assume the string input will match `^[a0-8]{2,15}$`, which isn't a subset of `^[0-9]*$`. In this case, no, you may not use a list of digits, since you can't use one to represent `1aa7708`, for example. You *can* use `[1, 1, 8, 8, 6, 4]` to represent `118864`, but this inconsistency is invalid by default.

---

I posted this after having come across numerous occurrences where I've had to ask about this in the comment section of the question, so I thought "why not post this here?". Surprisingly, this, AFAICT, hasn't ever been posted yet! I definitely have a positive opinion.

Answer (score 15):

## Metaprogramming languages may return a boolean by compiling/not compiling

For example, C++ template metaprogramming has no "return value".  A common way for a C++ template metaprogramming to reject something is to fail to compile (sometimes in a SFINAE way, sometimes not).

Comment: if C++ doesn't compile, it prints to STDERR?  If so, this could be generalized to allow boolean output by STDOUT vs STDERR.

Comment: @NathanMerrill If something does not compile, *it* doesn't output at all, I think. Expect compiling/not compiling (as described here).

Answer (score 14):

## Regexes may output a number via the number of matches

Or truthy / falsey as whether they match.

Comment: Plain regex submissions are still not generally accepted as valid so I'm not sure it's worth adding defaults for this very specific case that a lot of people don't accept at all.

Comment: Again , Retina.

Answer (score 14):

## An array may be represented in input as a begin pointer and an end pointer.

like what's done in C++ std

Comment: So you mean the iterator model that the C++ STL uses? I like this.

Comment: "*like what's done in C++ std*" - that needs to be fleshed out a bit more, maybe with an example, for those unfamiliar with C(++).

Comment: @Shaggy What other language have pointer but not enough knower know C/C++?

Comment: @l4m2 Well, C and C#. Both of them have pointers and both of them have lots of users that don't know how the C++ standard library works.

Answer (score 14):

## Floating point numbers may be represented as fractions.

For example, instead of literal `0.5` or `"0.5"`, the program can return `"1/2"` or `[1,2]`.
It's especially useful for languages without out-of-the-box floating point support.

Comment: But does the fraction have to be reduced?

Comment: I leave it up as a consensus. Reducing a fraction isn't a very complex task, but if it is necessary (due to some loophole I can't find currently) then reducing the fraction might be necessary.

Answer (score 14):

## Spreadsheet languages can take input from a specific cell / group of cells

Most Excel / Google Sheets answers seem to do this anyway, I don't know why it wasn't here.

For example, [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185921/100664) takes input through the A1 cell of a spreadsheet and performs operations on that to arrive at the final output.

Answer (score 14):

## Strings, arrays of characters, and arrays of bytes are interchangeable

Surprised this isn't here yet.

Languages like C don't really have strings, and arrays of bytes (`*char`) is already the common way of representing them. C++ does have strings but most CGSE answers still seem to prefer pointers to arrays of bytes.

Other languages like Rust have strings that are really inconvenient to work with, so I've already been using `[u8]` and `Vec<u8>` most of the time.

Answers may in some cases prefer using string tools on arrays, as long as the array will never have values over 255 taking input as a string then using functions like `.replace()` and `.split()` would be valid.

Or some languages, like regex, have only strings and would make some number challenges very inconvenient without using char values.

Actually this is already the default as stated [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8964/91213) but I think including it here is still valuable since this post is a lot easier to find.

Answer (score 13):

## Programs may write output to the clipboard

Complementing the [programs may take input from the clipboard](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11522/12012) proposal.

Comment: I agree with this, this is just like the proposal where  stack-based languages could write to the stack instead of outputting the result

Comment: This would mean that any program can compute the identity by doing nothing, right? That's kind-of weird.

Comment: While I agree that that is weird, I don't think that that is grounds to down vote. That is abusable in exactly 1 challenge, (and that loophole could be closed in that 1 challenge)

Comment: If you favor this proposal, you should also allow the identity to be computed by outputting on stdin.

Comment: @xnor: You can already do that in most languages by taking input by reference and not modifying it.  (In some languages like asm and classic C, you don't even have to declare args, so a function can just be empty or a single return instruction.  That's UB in C but will happen to work; compilers only warn instead of erroring when a function definition doesn't match how its called, and for use in other compilation units you can provide a non-prototype declaration.)  I guess in many other languages, it would save some space.  But only for the identify function.

Answer (score 13):

## For languages not containing a formal implementation of an input or output data type, the data type may be implemented as standardized for the language

For instance, in TIS-100, all inputs and outputs are integers ranging from -999 to 999. Therefore, arrays of positive integers are often terminated with zeroes. If a challenge asks to take in the array `[3, 4, 5, 6]` and return `[6, 8, 10, 12]`, in TIS-100 the implementation would be to take in the sequence `3 4 5 6 0` and output the sequence `6 8 10 12 0`.

Comment: I don't think "as standardized for the language" is very well-defined.

Answer (score 13):

## A multidimensional rectangular array may be represented by the list `[dimensions, flattened array]`

Comment: I have no strong opinion on this

Comment: This seems like a natural extension of [An array may be represented in input as a pointer and length](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13262/12012).

Answer (score 13):

## Programs may take input as arguments to command line flags

If a language has a command line flag in the form `--flag=arg`, input may be taken as the argument to that flag. For example:

```
./language -f --option=2 <prog>
```

Can be run for the input `2`.

Answer (score 13):

## A function can output by modifying a global variable *if that variable is automatically outputted/displayed*

It has been decided that in general, [functions may not output by just modifying a global variable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24058) because that would make it too much like a snippet, which is not allowed.

But what about languages where the value of that global variable is automatically outputted? For example, say there is a language where output is stored in an `output` string variable, and automatically displayed when the program finishes execution.

For example, in Scratch, the current ruling is that output must be displayed via the `say` block. However, in Scratch variables are shown automatically if not unchecked in the interface, just as `say` shows output automatically if the sprite is not checked as hidden in the interface. These should be allowed interchangeably since both output a value without any extra code at the call site.

Comment: Isn't this implied by [output to the screen](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7139/106545)?

Comment: @Bbrk24 I suppose so, I mainly posted this because I don't think Scratch answers should have to `say` the output

Answer (score 12):

## Programs may output using their return value

Iff it is legit regarding their specs and compilers.

Certain language treat programs as function, allowing programs to communicate via returns. Hence, we shoule allow such programs to be considered as whole, and not as snippet.

Comment: This has my upvote, because it is natural to languages as lua, where we often use this mechanism when creating an object.

Comment: Is this different from http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5330/8478?

Comment: @MartinEnder: This refers to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/88856/15 this answer here and explicitly concerns itself with return values of programs that are not integers. Which, incidentally, doesn't work in any environment I know of.

Comment: Ok, basically you are referring to the fact that you can embed Lua and have the host application handle any return values from the "main" Lua program in a suitable manner. It's just that the default Lua interpreter will effectively do nothing with the stack contents in that case, right?

Comment: @MartinEnder I think it is a generalisation of the one you're pointing to. I'm only creating this post as some PPCGer think it doesn't apply to returns, and I'd like to have a clear consensus on the return for programs, instead of one that simply embed it because of its definition.

Comment: @joey in lua, you can see this value the same way you would do for a library. As this is generally some short piece of code, you could use both `local answer = require"codegolf"` and `local answer = loadstring("program copypasted")()`

Answer (score 12):

## Numerical input and output can be given as a character code

For example, the input `64` can instead be given as the character `@`. This is mainly used for more esoteric languages that can only take input through character codes, for example brainfuck.

Comment: Note that this was already a consensus [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4719/76162), I'm just adding it here to make it easier to find.

Answer (score 12):

## An array may be represented as a buffer terminated with a sentinel value

This can be applied to both inputs and outputs for languages such as C and assembly. This is the default for C strings (a buffer of `char`, terminated with 0), but can be applied to any other data type.

As a more concrete example:

- An input array of positive integers can be taken as a single pointer of `uint32_t` or any other convenient integer type, which is assumed to terminate with a single zero.
- For an output array of positive integers, a C function can take an output pointer as the start of the buffer, write several numbers on that buffer, and then write a zero at the end.

It should be noted that the sentinel value must be the one that is guaranteed to not appear in any valid input or output, since their presence breaks the premise of the I/O method. For example, if the input may contain zeros, you cannot use zero as the sentinel value for the input array.

Answer (score 12):

## A program or function taking input by reference may output by modifying the input value in place

[A complement to this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13262/12012)

For example, in rust, one might write

```rust
fn a(v:&mut Vec<i32>){v.push(7);}
```

instead of

```rust
fn b(mut v: Vec<i32>)->Vec<i32>{v.push(7);return v;}
```

or

```rust
fn c(v:&mut Vec<i32>)->&mut Vec<i32>{v.push(7);return v;}
```

Answer (score 11):

## Programs may take input from the clipboard

Comment: why would anyone downvote this? i see literally no reason this shouldnt be allowed, its just another place to grab input from :P

Answer (score 11):

## SQL-based languages can output via `SELECT` or `PRINT`

We have countless examples of highly upvoted answers sending SQL output to either the *results* pane (via `SELECT`) or to the *messages* pane (via `PRINT`), depending on which works the best and is shorter for a particular challenge.

Both are acceptable.

(This uses terminology from MS SQL Management Studio, other platforms/clients likely have equivalents.)

Other outputs may be possible as well, such as outputting graphical results to the [spatial results pane](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/191294/draw-the-biohazard-symbol/191323#191323).

Answer (score 10):

## BASIC and related languages may take input via DATA / READ

In various dialects of BASIC, you can include data in the source code by using the `DATA` statement:

```
DATA abc, xyz
DATA 2, 3, 5, 7, 11
```

<sup>(Examples are written in QBasic because that's what I know.)</sup>

You access this data by using `READ`:

```
READ str1$, str2$
FOR i = 1 TO 5
  READ primes(i)
NEXT
```

This input method is idiomatic for BASIC.

Comment: Is this basically the equivalent of `final static` in Java?

Comment: @NathanMerrill I don't think it's similar at all, actually. Based on 2 mins of research on Java, it looks like `final` is equivalent to `CONST` in QBasic, and `static` doesn't have an equivalent because QBasic doesn't have classes. `READ` is like `INPUT`, except the input is stored in the program with `DATA` so the user doesn't have to retype it each time they run the code.

Comment: I guess I don't follow: when would you use const vs data/read? It seems like reading data already stored in your program is a waste of CPU cycles.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Initializing arrays is one use case, since as far as I know BASIC doesn't have anything like C's `int array[3] = {2,3,5};`. In QBasic you `DIM array(3)` and then you can either do `array(1)=2: array(2)=3: array(3)=5` (etc.) or you can write an easy-to-read `FOR` loop as above and put `DATA 2, 3, 5` in the program. For large amounts of data (like layouts for a maze game), it might be better programming practice to put the data into a different file, but in the interests of being self-contained and not having to deal with file I/O, the `DATA` statement is often used instead.

Comment: Note also that `READ` does not result in fixed values like `CONST` does. If you do `CONST pi = 3.14`, you can never modify that value (assigning to `pi` thereafter is a syntax error). But you can `READ x` and then do `x=x+1` (or whatever). And you can `READ` multiple different data values into the same variable (in a loop, say).

Comment: The argument is that the Data command effectively creates unnamed constant variables (and read just reads them), so the fact that you can modify the read ones is irrelevant IMO. I'm on the fence here: the syntax is similar to input from the user, but it also feels like reading from a variable.

Comment: The ZX80 and ZX80 do not have DATA/READ keywords in its default interpreter. One has to store data in variables, or in `REM` statements and - in this case - read each byte by using the `PEEK` keyword.

Comment: Would the very similar `<DATA>` be accepted in Perl? (docs: http://perldoc.perl.org/SelfLoader.html#The-__DATA__-token).

Comment: @DLosc - is there a consensus as to what portions of the `Read` and `Data` statements are to be included in the bytecount? Is [this Yabasic snippet](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7v4hjiqGDEBaaM/7t4@ioUFGXmphZrmGhyufkHKWQq2CoYKoT4K5hwKSgEuTq6wOQzNYECAUGefiFIIn6uESEQI00hRpr/BwA) scored correctly?

Comment: @TaylorRaine That's a good question. I don't think there is a consensus. My initial reaction is that `DATA` should be included in the bytecount--only the data itself should not be. But that still raises questions about the comma in `DATA 2,3`...

Comment: @DLosc [Meta Question about the above](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24657/61846)

Answer (score 10):

## Numerical input and output can be given as a string of digits and vice-versa

As long as the input/output format is consistent, you may take a numerical output such as `f(123)` as a string `f("123")` and vice-versa. This will also open up other string methods, such as taking a number as a list of digits as per [this consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2216/76162).

Note that if different behaviours are expected for numbers with leading zeroes, then you will have to take input as a string instead, since strings with leading zeroes will be mapped to the same number.

You may not add leading zeroes if you are using string input instead of a number.

Answer (score 10):

## Image output may consist of a matrix or 2d array for raster images

This is relevant e.g. for [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) challenges. (e.g. for languages that otherwise have no way of writing an image file or opening a window for the graphical display)

Answer (score 10):

## Spreadsheet languages may output through cell values

Most Excel / Google Sheets answers seem to do this anyway, I don't know why it wasn't here.

For example, [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185921/100664) outputs a created piece of text to the cell it's pasted into.

Answer (score 9):

## Programs may input/output bytes in a bit-serial or 8-bit parallel manner with a clock and enable signal

This is mainly applicable to HDLs such as Verilog, as well as other embedded devices (such as microcontrollers). Currently, `$display` is capable of writing to standard out in a simulator, but of course, not in a physical FPGA.

Comment: Why require an enable signal? If you take a clock as input, and can output a bit with every clock pulse, the enable signal is just wasting code. (I've used this in a submission already, although the question specified I/O methods explicitly rather than defaulting to this post.)

Comment: @ais523 Sorry, I didn't think of that when I created this. It makes sense that the clock could be stopped, at least for input, but not sure how a program could communicate that it wants to delay output for a few clock cycles while calculating.

Comment: If the problem's simple enough, the program can guarantee that it'll never have to delay output. (Note that you could define a fairly slow clock speed.) Of course, for some algorithms (especially ones that are slower than constant or linear-bounded time) the enable signal might be required.

Comment: Why need a clock signal? It is also possible to just use UART with a given Clock Frequency. And why 8 Bit? If you want what stop you from using 4, 12, 16 or 27 Bits?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 There is often no good way to perform sequential or stateful computation in synthesizable Verilog without a clock signal. 8-bit is in alignment with the fact that 8-bit ASCII is common; you can submit a new answer that allows non-8-bit parallel inputs. Additionally, to output/input data a communication clock is required, whether for each word/bit or to actually run a UART. I would strongly doubt that *anyone* would want to spend valuable bytes on writing a UART, except perhaps in code-bowling challenges.

Answer (score 9):

## Mappings may be used in place of functions

([Discussion in The Nineteenth byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/conversation/mappings))

Whenever a function is expected, a mapping such as a dictionary/hashmap or array may be used instead.

Arguments for:

- in many languages, there is no syntax difference (K, MATLAB, Ruby - a `Proc` can be used with the same `[]` syntax as a `Hash`)
- disallowing it borders on an [unobservable requirement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11197), particularly in the above languages, and having different rules for different languages is [generally discouraged](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10003)
- it allows removing boilerplate in challenges which boil down to "construct a mapping and then look up into it", like (Python) `lambda x:{k:v for k,v in ...}[x]`

Arguments against:

- it feels a bit cheaty to me

Comment: I haven't _downvoted_, because I know mathematically a function can be viewed as just a (possibly infinite) mapping. But I also haven't upvoted because, as you say, it feels a little cheaty. I think if the return value isn't callable/executable in your chosen language, we shouldn't assume an interpreter to run it.

Comment: I have no reasons to disagree for challenges where the output is completely deterministic (i.e. a pure function), assuming that *you can extract the output for any given input in finite time*. The answer is invalid if the premise is not satisfied (which is equivalent to a function that falls into an infinite loop for that input). One thing to note is that we're already allowing this for [tag:sequence] challenges in the form of infinite lazy lists.

Comment: Even if this is to be allowed as an output method, it should certainly not be allowed as an *input* method (for problems where you take a function as input), since a mapping includes extra information that a function does not, namely an enumeration of all items in the domain.

Comment: In languages without built-in mapping type, mappings are usually represented as lists of tuples. But using lists of tuples in place of functions feels even more cheaty.

Answer (score 9):

## When printing to STDOUT, you may have any number of trailing whitespace

Answer (score 9):

## Programs may take input from a generator or iterator

We already have a [rule that programs may output via a generator](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10753/91213). Just for completeness, I think we should specify it's a valid input method as well.

Example in rust:

```rs
|t:Box<dyn Iterator>|t.flatten()
```

Other example, taking input via the returned generator in python:

```py
def k():
    yield "Hello, "+str(yield "What is your name")
```

Which can be used like

```py
t = k()
print(next(k))
print(k.send("Charlie"))
```

Another example:

```
def k(f):
    return [int(next(f)),*f]
```

Comment: This would also work as (e.g. in Python) a function that takes a generator as an argument, and to take input, use `next(g)` (instead of `yield`).

Answer (score 9):

### Infinite lists / generators / iterators may be taken as indexing functions

An infinite list / generator / iterator may be taken as a function that indexes into the value.

For example, if taking the infinite list of fibonacci numbers `[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]` you may instead take a function that:

- When given 0, returns 1
- When given 1, returns 1
- When given 2, returns 2
- When given 3, returns 3
- When given 4, returns 5

etc.

Comment: May finite lists be taken this way?

Comment: @noodleman I think that falls under [mappings being equivalent to functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22401/100664) (or if you don't think it does you might want to make a separate post), this is an edgecase mostly for languages that don't have built-in infinite lists.

Answer (score 8):

## Programs running on FPGAs may take input or give output through transceivers.

Comment: I'm not familiar with FPGAs, but I would upvote if there's no way to encode data into which transceiver is being used or how.

Comment: Responding to the above comment which I missed five years ago - you pick a transceiver and its clock/config at design time. IMO using multiple transceivers would be in the same spirit as using multiple function arguments (in the sense of a arguments in a language like C)

Answer (score 7):

## Assembly language / machine code must take input and output as defined by an ABI for the platform that predates the challenge

For example, most commonly used ABIs for x86 state that 32-bit integer outputs are returned in the `%eax` register. As such, that's a valid way to output a 32-bit integer. However, outputting in, e.g., `%esp` would not be valid, unless a pre-existing ABI can be located where that's considered a valid method of output.

(Some background for people unaware of assembly language technology: an ABI, or Application Binary Interface, is a specification for how pieces of code within a particular program, on a particular platform, communicate with each other via the state of the processor. Most ABIs specify specific memory addresses and/or registers to be used for the communication.)

This is outright intended as a competing answer to the other assembly-language-related answers, because I feel they're too permissive and could lead to loopholes in which bytes are moved from the program to a selection of a register/memory address. (See [this answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12833/62131) and the corresponding question for more detail.)

Comment: Assembly is free for platform etc it can have arg as one register and return its result as a flag... If it has to communicate or to be used to C language programs than yes has to follow API...

Comment: In real-world hand-optimized assembly language, it's normal for some functions to use their own custom calling convention for input and output registers.  If the language of your answer is machine code, it makes sense to think about a machine code caller.  I agree that outputting via the stack pointer wouldn't be plausible, but any other register is fine, including a boolean in FLAGS.  See [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165020) for x86(-64) specifically.

Answer (score 7):

## If a program is supposed to take a whole number as input, it may accept the number as a unary string.

Comment: I think this is allowed because of https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5343/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-unary

Answer (score 7):

## Functions may generate different output via different exceptions if they could be caught using different code

For example, in C++, you could use `throw 1;` and `throw true;` to output two distinct values. They could be caught by `catch(int)` and `catch(bool)` in a `try` block respectively. (In most other languages, you could only throw values in an exception class.)

Answer (score 7):

## Image output may consist of a pixel-shader

A *pixel-shader* is a function that takes the `(x,y)` coordinates of a pixel as an input, and outputs the color of this pixel (e.g. a scalar for grayscale images, a tuple for color images, a boolean value for binary images etc.)

This is relevant e.g. for [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) challenges. (also for `GLSL / Shadertoy` answers.)

Comment: Isn't this explicitly disallowed for [tag:graphical-output] at the moment? I suspect it had a good reason too. Same for your other [suggestion here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18304/).

Comment: @Mast It seems to me that the tag wiki only addresses ASCII-art, but these two types do not seem to be captured, that is why I also thought it would be a good idea to clarify that explicitly.

Comment: I find it weird that this lets solutions not specify the size of the image. Or does the function gave to produce some different value indicating out-of-bounds?

Comment: @xnor The size of the image should be specified, but I think the key is that if you want a bigger resolution of the same image you could just sample (x,y) more finely as an alternative to defining a bigger resolution in the start.

Comment: @flawr I'm not clear how you'd sample more finely. Are (x,y) floats?

Comment: If we normalize the coordinates e.g. to `[0,1]^2` then `(x,y)` could be interpreted as floats, right. If you're using integers then the program itself also takes the limits (e.g. in shadertoy this is implicit)

Answer (score 7):

## A natural number may be represented as a collection of n empty collections, and a string as a collection of such numbers

In languages that do not have numbers or strings but do have lists, stacks, or other collections, a natural number (including 0) may be represented by a collection of empty collections, where the length of the outer collection represents the natural number. So `[]` would represent 0, `[[], [], []]` would represent 3, and so on. Strings may be represented as collections of these natural numbers, as Unicode codepoints are unsigned.

Comment: Even if the language does not have a notion of a number or string, the interpreter can be made to do the necessary I/O via such conversion. Flurry already does that (a number is not a built-in, but stack contents are translated from/to numbers when the program starts/ends).

Comment: @Bubbler That's totally reasonable, but one of the main ideas of the language I was thinking about is that the interpreter has no conception of anything that isn't a stack.

Answer (score 7):

## In stack-based languages, inputs may be pushed onto the stack at the start of the program, and the output may be the top element on the stack at the end of the program

This has already been [proposed for functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8493/95792), but it should also be allowed for full programs.

Answer (score 7):

## When returning a set, one can return a map, where values are ignored

Answer (score 6):

### A full program may be input or output any time a function could

If we can do this:

```
x=>y=>x+y
```

Then we can do this:

```
print("print(int(input())+"+input()+")")
```

Comment: That Python code is...a curried program. what.

Comment: +1 from me. If functions can return other functions, full programs should be able to print other full programs

Answer (score 5):

## [black-box functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13706/24877) to be taken as input can be assumed to be predefined under a given name only if they cannot be passed as an argument.

This holds for languages that do have classical functions, but cannot pass around functions like other values. This holds for instance for: Java up to version 7

This proposition is the opposite of [that one](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13707/24877) which does not have this restriction.

Comment: -1 because I don't think this is well-defined (e.g. are functions in Underload passed as an argument? What about Python's functions, which aren't black box because you can inspect their bytecode?)

Comment: Also, [Don't allow / ask for different things in languages with different capabilities](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10003/61384) (related issue).

Comment: @EsolangingFruit That doesn't seem to be the case here, it's not the challenge asking for different stuff for different languages, it's more like allowing more languages to compete by using more lenient consensuses for them, since otherwise they couldn't compete at all.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Fair, but my view is that, to avoid ambiguity and rule-lawyering, we should allow *all* languages to do this.

Answer (score 5):

## Functions may output via throwing the output value as an exception, if it could be caught, and read by the code catching the exception

Answer (score 5):

### Programs may take input based on their executable name.

i. e. `argv[0]` in C or `$0` in shell-like languages.
Thus the script `parrot.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo $0
```

if having multiple [links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ln_(Unix)) to it

```sh
ln parrot.sh foo
ln parrot.sh bar
```

prints different outputs

```sh
PATH=$(pwd) foo     #  will print e.g. /tmp/foo
PATH=$(pwd) bar     #  will print e.g. /tmp/bar
```

NB:
This rule is not applicable if the executable [file name *has* to be a certain string](/a/1072/) to fulfill the programming challenge’s specifications at hand.

Comment: This is a [default loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1072/92901). If taking input through the executable name, those bytes count towards the score.

Comment: @Dingus no, as in the user must rename the executable to a string, and that string is one of the inputs. It is not stored program data

Comment: I don't really see how this isn't stored program data (where the data is one of the inputs). Leaving that aside, how is this different from hardcoding?

Comment: In some sense I guess this isn't much different from taking input from a file, which is allowed. But I imagine that file is meant to be a fixed target, not a moving one.

Comment: I don't really see how this *is* stored data. Instead of running `./program arg1 arg2`, you run `mv program arg0; ./arg0 arg1 arg2`.

Comment: Or you can run it without `mv` via something like `exec -a arg0 ./program arg1 arg2` in bash or `execlp("program", arg0, arg1, arg2, 0)` in C. From an OS perspective, `$0` is just a parameter that we usually leave set to the default value.

Comment: I'll say, I don't know of a situation where this could save bytes, but I don't see a reason to ban it. It's not the same as the loophole of assuming the program will have a fixed value _controlled by the programmer_.

Comment: Can someone give an example of a challenge that gets more interesting this way?

Answer (score 4):

### Functions are allowed to overwrite global data structures as its output

The premise of this is that your language does not support built-in return values.

For example, Assembly language doesn't have a built-in way of returning values, therefore a global accumulator is permitted as a return value.

In Scratch, there are no functions (only procedures), therefore global variables are allowed as the output of the function.

In stack-based languages, functions take arbitary items from the stack, and modify the stack. The return value is therefore stored onto the stack.

Comment: In Scratch, variables can be outputted via say. And in a most stack-based languages, there are commands to output.  So only if your language has NO output method.

Comment: @emanresuA In Scratch, variables are shown automatically if not unchecked in the interface, in a similar way to how `say` shows output automatically if the sprite is not checked as hidden in the interface. Do you think in this case it is OK to not use `say`, or would you still say that `say` is better?

Comment: @Jacob That's a good question, and I'd suggest making a separate post for that.

Answer (score 4):

### Output may have any number of leading white space.

There is already a suggestion concerning [*trailing* blanks](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24952/94076).
This is about *preceding* blanks.
Why should this be acceptable?
Suppose you wanna to write a `program` in Pascal that prints the answer to the ultimate question of life, the universe, and everything.
You’ll simply write

```pascal
program p(output);begin writeLn(42)end.
```

However, when the destination is a `text` file (like `output` is), for numeric `write` arguments there’s an invisible **implementation-defined** default minimum-width specifier.
Thus this `program` *may* print:

```
         42
```

i. e. the `program` is effectively doing a

```pascal
writeLn(output, 42:11)
```

The `:11` indicates the *minimum* number of characters the argument occupies (for *numeric* arguments, for `char`, `string` and `Boolean` it specifies *the exact* width).
The default value is *implementation-defined* thus different compilers may have different default values, possibly even `1`.
If leading white space is prohibited you’ll have to write `:1` yourself.

Ultimately, like trailing blanks it does not inhibit legibility.
Specifically for many numbers it actually improves legibility, that’s why Pascal allows and some compilers do have a reasonably large default minimum-width.

Answer (score 4):

## When taking a set, one can take a map from the set to an well agreed value

This allows some languages to easier check if element in a set with mapped value `true`: `X[i]` is shorter than `X.contains(i)`

Answer (score 3):

## Functions may take input from the output of a callback function

The callback function should be provided using a valid input method.

Complementing

- [Functions may return a function that returns the result](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11317/25180) (outputted function may output)
- [Functions may take multiple arguments via currying](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8427/25180) (outputted function may take input (and also output))
- [Functions may output by calling a callback function or event](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11324/25180) (inputted function may receive output)

Answer (score 3):

## Languages that output on program completion can assume termination even when built to hang for the purpose of providing output.

That is, if a program is built to not a terminate, and requires output while running (say, for an [Internal Truth Machine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/198288/internal-truth-machine), or [Scream Very Loudly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/200306/scream-very-loudly), etc.), the program can assume to crash or be manually stopped to verify the output scales appropriately.

The argument for this is that several languages (such as Processing[Java], for example) will not print output unless a certain state is reached (the end of a Draw statement in Processing, per se). This means that programs stuck in While Loops would never provide any output. Languages like GolfScript, though it has a Print function, also doesn't *actually* Print the output until the program is complete - it holds the print in a buffer until the program eventually stops (for any reason, [even interrupting](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/37Cg2rA2Jd/6/38A)). Likewise, GS prints the stack when it closes for any reason (depending on your interpreter; TIO fails at this) - so filling the stack with infinite As then waiting for a crash would *also* be within this parameter.

Several languages would otherwise fail infinitely-printing hanging challenges due to the act they wouldn't ever be capable of printing given the assumed infinite time and memory, which is the main argument for allowing this sort of output.

Comment: As written, this would allow a GolfScript program to “solve” the halting problem: push false onto the stack, then run a universal Turing machine, then pop false and push true. If this is to be allowed, it should only be allowed for mechanisms that don’t allow the program to change its mind later.

Comment: I think we should not allow this. Verifying that the program is correct is essentially undecidable and if a program doesn't give output when it enters infinite loop, it will never give an output.

Comment: I, too, think we should not allow this. 1) It requires external input, namely some decision as to whether or not to terminate the program yet. 2) If the challenge is to output the count of objects that match a certain criterion, this would allow a program which searched an infinite search space, which would find any matching objects, but which would never know whether or not future searching would find any more.

Answer (score 2):

## Functions may output by calling a callback function or event

The callback function should be provided using a valid input method.

Example in JavaScript that outputs `Hello world!`:

```
f=>f("Hello world!")
```

This may be shorter than returning a value in some languages:

```
import random as r
def f(x):
    q=r.random()
    return(q+q/2)/2
```

As opposed to:

```
import random as r
def f(x,g):
    q=r.random()
    g((q+q/2)/2)
```

Comment: I don't see why this should be useful, considering you can just return the result.

Comment: Never mind, I see why this might be useful. Upvoted.

Comment: @Challenger5 Please explain why.

Comment: @haykam In a language like Python, something like `import os [\n] def f(k):return os.system(k)` is longer than `import os [\n] def f(k,g):g(os.system(k))`

Comment: @Challenger5, the point of specifying default I/O methods is to allow answers to use idiomatic I/O, not to allow golfing a byte off `print`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Might it be more idiomatic in some languages to use [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) rather than returning?

Answer (score 1):

## Classes, objects or other entities may have separate methods to read the input and return the result

This includes the constructor and destructor.

Comment: Can the destructor return the result? That seems to be along the same lines as outputting to `/dev/null`.

Comment: I don't believe a C++ destructor is allowed to return anything.

Comment: Is it okay if the destruct function output something?

Answer (score 1):

## Functions may output by setting the default variable(s)

Perl has a "default" scalar `$_`. Unless specifically *overridden* by the `=~` operator, regular expressions and such will operate on this variable. It also has `@_`, the "default" array, and `%_`, the "default" hash.

Comment: I don't see how this is any different than hardcoding I/O with variables, which is not allowed.

Comment: @Mego What do you mean? I'm not entirely sure what "hardcoding I/O with variables" refers to.

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2423/45941

Comment: Ah, I see then.

Comment: This is basically Ans in TI-Basic, and isn't too different from the top of the stack in stack based languages. Following functions if defined in the right way don't need to specify the variable name to use it. It's only technically a variable, but don't need to be used like a variable. I don't see good reasons to disallow it.

Answer (score 0):

## Cellular automata and 2d languages may take input by interfacing with a user-built structure

Many of these languages do not have any other way to take input. By "interfacing", I mean additional structures being created by the user to interact with the existing code in a way that provides only the necessary information (such as some sort of serial representation of the inputted values) in a way that could feasibly be used by the user's program and controlled by another turing-complete automaton (so not in a tiny space in the middle of the program, or in an area that will be overwritten).

Comment: This would seem similar to the "Languages without input like /// may input through insertion into their source code"

Answer (score 0):

## Cellular automata and 2d languages may output by interfacing with a user-built structure

Many of these languages do not have any other way to produce (non-visual) output. By "interfacing", I mean additional structures being created by the user to interact with the existing code in a way that the program provides only the necessary information (such as some sort of serial representation of the outputted values) in a way that could feasibly be used by the user's program to control another turing-complete automaton (so not in a tiny space in the middle of the program, or in an area that will be overwritten).

Answer (score 0):

## Program may take one argument as one input and filename of another input

This allows "input two letters, concat them" in bash

```
cat $1; echo $1
```

Like [Programs may take input based on their executable name](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20613/76323), your filename should be possible to carry any possible input. If input may contain `*` and your filesystem doesn't support it, you can't use this method.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of [Submissions may use list of strings instead of multi-line strings](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17095/10868)

## Submissions may use an arbitrarily nested list of lists of strings to represent newline-separated chunks

Well I didn't explain it well so here's an example:

Say the challenge specifies

```
abc
def

ghi
jkl


lmnop
qrs

tuv
wxyz
```

This could instead be treated as `[[[abc, def], [ghi, jkl]], [[lmnop, qrs], [tuv,wxyz]]]`

Answer (score -1):

## Property setters may take input from the set value

Comment: This could use some elaboration. Why is this not a special case of a function taking input as function arguments? And why would anyone answer a PPCG question with a property setter?

Answer (score -1):

## Source files or libraries may output via the return value importing them

For example, this PHP code has no effects as a complete program:

```
<?php return 'Hello, world!';
```

But as a library named '1.php', the return value could be printed to stdout using this:

```
<?php echo include '1.php';
```

Answer (score -2):

## Program may take input from environment variables

Environment variables are generally supported by many languages:

- C program may access environment variables from `getenv`
- Python program may access environment variables from `os.environ`
- etc.

Environment variables are typically a constant in program, which is quite different from a *variable* in languages.

Many real word software supports / suggests user config some options from environments. For example, [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/), [aws cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html), even [`ls` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ls) ...

Environment variables are similar to function submissions which accept its arguments by name instead by position.

Comment: I'm going to say no, because this is equivalent to taking input from a pre-defined name in e.g. Bash

Answer (score -3):

## Programs may use the camera and microphone

I wouldn't expect to see this very often, but it could be applicable to my upcoming challenge.

Comment: This has my vote

Comment: I don't think this should be a default. Definitely fine if asker specifies it as a valid input format for the question! Excited to see your upcoming challenge involving this.

Answer (score -4):

## `eval` is considered an interpreter and the `eval`'d code may output via the return value

For example, this PHP code has no effects as a complete program in the `php` interpreter:

```
return 'Hello, world!';
```

But the return value is accessible using the `eval` interpreter:

```
<?php echo eval("return 'Hello, world!';");
```

Comment: Just for clarification, this only applies in challenges that allow snippets, correct? I don't think you're suggesting we allow snippets by default, but just to be safe...

Comment: @ETHproductions Rewrote to avoid mentioning that.

Answer (score -4):

## Languages that cannot obtain world-state-sensitive information can accept the information as an additional input

Some challenges may require the use of the current time, cryptographic random values, or other information present on the system used to run the program. Additionally, many languages (for various reasons) lack the ability to access this information, and thus compete at all.

To overcome this, answers may accept such information as additional input *in a minimally processed format* (eg: unix timestamp instead of a date string, a single random value instead of a random generator function).

Comment: Well, cryptographic random values can still be generated in Turing tarpits.

Comment: @StephenLeppik I was thinking more of completely deterministic languages where you would need the random seed for any subsequent random values.

Comment: I don't like this idea (it's related to [this meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10003/34531). Accessing system information can require quite some bytes (maybe an import and/or system calls with long function names). Taking just another input variable instead is an unfair advantage. We always had challenges which cannot be solved with all languages (e.g. graphical output), but most can, so it's not a problem.

Comment: @nimi This isn't for those languages that can access system information/resources only in an expensive manner. This proposal is for languages (like brainfuck) that have no way to access that information/those resources. Because BF has no source of randomness, this proposal would allow BF to take a seed value as an additional input to be fed into a PRNG.

Comment: @Mego: yes, I know, maybe I wasn't clear enough. My point is: getting some system information via additional input is usually much cheaper (in bytes) than having to call some system library functions. Some languages would be allowed to use the former, others not, although both compete within the same challenge. That's unfair. ...

Comment: @Mego: (cont.) Stupid example to illustrate the point: challenge: output the system time. Fictional stack based esolang #1: `St` (system call "time" + implicit print -> 2 bytes). Fictional stack based esolang #2: No systems calls available, therefore the time is expected as input on top of the stack + implicit print -> 0 bytes). #2 wins, because #1 has to use the system calls. Same example for non-esolangs: `import Time;f=print(system_time())` vs. `f(x)=print(x)`.

Comment: @nimi That falls afoul of [this loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11355/45941).

Comment: @Mego: True for my mini example. However, the advantage for #2 remains even if the task is more complicated.

Answer (score -5):

## Languages that *do* have I/O capabilities may take input via hardcoding

i.e. you may insert input into the code directly, as if it were an output only language like ///

Comment: Interesting. I'd be curious to see the reasoning for these downvotes

Comment: I think its because this becomes more of a snippet format

Comment: This is already listed [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/10553#10553).

Comment: @Steffan it is not, read the titles of both very closely

Answer (score -6):

## Functions may get input from predefined variables in languages where this is standard

In some BASIC dialects, the standard way to implement functions is to use `GOSUB` (similar to `CALL` in assembly).
You can't pass variables to `GOSUB`, so function arguments/returns are just global variables.
If you need a function that takes a number as input, and outputs that number multiplied by 2, the normal way to do this would be something like:

```
@TIMES2
 OUT=IN*2
RETURN
```

To call it, you would do

```
IN=7
GOSUB @TIMES2
'result is in variable OUT
```

The exact same process is allowed in assembly languages.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to allow things that are "Kind of like functions" just because a language doesn't have functions. As long as an answer can be written as a full program using existing allowed I/O I don't think we need a special exception to allow answers in "function-like behavior".

Comment: Then why do we allow the same thing in "assembly" languages?

Comment: Answers talking about "Assembly" refer to any language which does not have an output other than storing things in a special register. If a program can be written in the language which inputs and outputs in a more standard way then it doesn't need those allowances.

Comment: Registers in assembly language are analogous to local vars and temporaries (like a return-value object) in languages like C.  Languages that don't *have* locals or return-values don't have anything like registers.  I didn't downvote, though; if the language has a `gosub` and real-world (non-golf) usage does write "functions" this way, there's certainly an argument to be made.  The justification by analogy with asm is pretty weak, though.  In asm you need registers just to evaluate expressions, and there are only a small fixed number of them.

Answer (score -6):

## Functions may output by modifying a global variable

This is similar to [Functions may output by modifying their arguments or writing to out arguments](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4942/84844)
The difference is that we don't pass any reference to the function, instead we declare a global variable the function is aware of and assigns the result to it.
Obviously the global variable declaration used must be included in the score.

For example a C function which was like this:

```
f(x,Type*r){... ;*r=result;}
```

May be

```
Type r;f(x){.... ;r=result;}
```

Comment: I used this method on a challenge but never seen before, no one complained but since I was  not sure I searched here in the Meta.. The only similar answer was the one linked, the title mentioned "write to out arguments" but here we don't use out argument but out global variable

Comment: I'm not a fan of this.  I think it's basically becoming a snippet format, and I don't really feel like a case for this has been made here.

Comment: @Grain Ghost thanks, I'm not sure too, I would probably downvote this, that's why I posted it, I think it's good to clearly define if it is acceptable or not before it become used. As for now there are only 2 answers using this I'm aware of(one is mine). I'll correct mine and warn the other in a couple of days

Answer (score -6):

## Programs may output only one copy as two intended ones if they're always same

This usually apply to open-ended questions if possible

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this proposal (and given the lack of votes, I don't think anyone else does either)

Comment: I think the user is proposing that outputting the answer twice is reasonable.

Answer (score -6):

## You can have as many newlines after your output as you want.

It doesn’t matter what type of newline.

Comment: Already covered here: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24952/91213

Comment: @mousetail that’s whitespace not newline

Comment: A newline is a type of white-space, along with tabs, spaces, and some weird Unicode chars

Comment: I concur with @moustail: [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_442) defines _white space_ as, quote: A sequence of one or more characters that belong to the **space** character class as defined via the _LC_CTYPE_ category in the current locale. In the POSIX locale, white space consists of one or more <blank> ( <space> and <tab> characters), <newline>, <carriage‑return>, <form‑feed>, and <vertical‑tab> characters.

Answer (score -6):

## Submissions to [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) challenges may take no input and output a (potentially infinite) set of all possible truthy/falsey outputs.

If the challenge is "Is the number even or odd?", a submission could output a set of all even numbers (or, a set of all odd numbers).

If the challenge is "Is the number a fibonacci number?", a submission could output a set of all fibonacci numbers.

A few submissions in TypeScript’s type system have used this where the submission is a union type (like a set) and you get truthy/falsey by whether assigning a variable to the union throws an error or not. I don’t see why this wouldn’t be allowed in other languages as well.

Comment: One weird consequence of this is allowing you to solve the halting problem as a decision challenge, even though it's formally undecidable.

Comment: @xnor Not sure that’s true, how do you get the set of all halting programs without solving the halting problem?

Comment: Enumerate all programs. Run program \$i\$ for \$j\$ steps, for every pair \$(i,j)\$ of positive integers in some enumeration of those pairs. If program \$i\$ halted on exactly step \$j\$, output it.

Comment: Hm, interesting. I still don’t really see why this I/O format can’t be allowed, though—the true/false is just the member function

Answer (score -7):

## Functions may return multiple values, even if the question only asks for one.

As long as one of them is the requested output, the function is considered valid.

Comment: This would definitely cause problems for decision problem challenges if you could just return `[True, False]` no matter the input.

Comment: Suggest editing this to “as long as a *specified* one of them is the requested output”.

Comment: Anders Kaseorg's suggestion makes a lot of sense - it allows people to output extraneous information without cheating on questions.

Comment: Yes, @AndersKaseorg's suggestion is what I was going for here. This answer is so far in the hole I'm afraid editing it wouldn't do much. Feel free to make a new answer.

Answer (score -8):

## Programs running under Unix may produce output by overwriting their command-line arguments, which changes what `ps` reports.

I'm posting this because it was brought up as a loophole in [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/61388/14031) to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/61115/14031).  I personally think it should *not* be allowed, because it's obscure, not available in all languages, and ephemeral (someone has to run `ps` while the program is still executing).

Comment: this seems to be a special case of "functions may use out parameters"

Comment: but ps doesn't report it after the program ends :(

Answer (score -8):

## You may output with reasonable constant trailing and leading data

This does not apply to [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) challenges.

For example, if you need to output `3`, you can output `__3__`.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: I'm not sure (I didn't downvote it), but I think it's because people feel like this needs to be more restricted. Underscores feel somewhat off—maybe restrict it to whitespace and certain other characters? Plus, there are other answers exactly like this.

Answer (score -21):

## Dynamic creation of a "fake" STDIN, when one isn't present (creating also a separation between the code and the input).

For example, Javascript doesn't have `STDIN`(for obvious reasons).

One could make something like `function(a){[code here]}` and only count the content inside it + 1.

On php, one can read from `STDIN` using `$f=fread(STDIN,1024);` and this would count only as 2 chars.

On other languages, this would vary a bit.

Any questions, I may answer on the comments.

Comment: Isn't the PHP example actually reading from STDIN? In which case, why shouldn't all of those bytes count?

Comment: Depending on the way you handle it, if you read everything on STDIN at once, you can consider it a single input. I don't know if I'm making myself clear. But if your code is restricted to only 1 read to the STDIN, you can only consider the size in bytes of the name of the var. If multiple accesses are made (loops, conditions, partial reads...), everything is counted on the code.

Comment: @MartinBüttner He's referring to the fact that different languages have different character counts for an STDIN read. Also, shouldn't this be CW?

Comment: @TheDoctor Doesn't matter anyway - no rep gain/loss for meta.

Answer (score -29):

## Output is saved in a certain variable at the time the program has finished execution

This eliminates the disadvantages languages like Java have when printing `System.out.println("asdf")`

For languages without variables this could be top of the stack etc...

Comment: This essentially makes the submission a snippet instead of a full program, which the other meta question decided should *not* be a valid default.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Unless the programming language is, of course, a turing machine. (I do vote for placing the tape head at the return value)

Comment: In C#, a lambda is more a variable than a function.  Lambdas are build on top of [Delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx). Are they still valid? (By [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4942/15214), i think so)

Comment: In what way is this fundamentally different from [the same rule about functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4942/90841)? Why is it allowed for functions and not for full programs?

Answer (score -47):

## Programs may take input by assuming it is stored in predefined variables.

Comment: -1 (Can't vote)

Comment: This just skips the "reading" step of a program. I don't think programs should be allowed to assume the output of an arbitrary computation, e.g. the one asked for in the question, is stored in a predefined variable either.

Comment: @djechlin we are intentionally separating input/output methods.  Outputting on variables is listed here: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6965/20198

Comment: Okay, I still don't think you can skip the "reading" step of a program any more than you can skip the "writing" step of a program. That's all I'm trying to say.

Comment: I'm confused what you are talking about.  Programs have input and output.  We define valid input methods (such as reading from a file, or parameters to a function), and valid output methods (writing to a file, or return values).  This post is directly targeted at input methods.  There is *another* answer on this question targeted at output methods.  We split them so people can vote separately.

Comment: This is most relevant to the Sinclair ZX80 and ZX81 BASIC.