# Can the binary representations of argv[n] be used for numeric input?

Tags: discussion, code-golf, defaults

TL;DR: Is `int d = *(int*)argv[1];` allowed to obtain a integer input?

A special case of this question: [Can numeric input/output be in the form of byte values?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-the-form-of-byte-values/4719#4719)

This is mostly for C, C++, assembly and languages with similar properties.

Lets say the programs needs a integer or floating point as input. Is it legal to obtain this value by interpreting the binary representation of `argv[1][0]`...`argv[1][n]` as integer of floating point? In C you can do that with `a=*(int*)argv[1];`

A possible problem is that this makes it harder to input numbers where some bytes of it, except the highest byte, are `0`. In C strings are terminated with `'\0'` or `0`, and therefore `argv` on most OSs. So to input a number which has a 0-byte in it you have to use more than 1 `argv` argument.

###### How argv is filled in memory

On my Linux Debian AMD64, `argv` is in memory like this.

```
  V--- argv[0] points here        V--- argv[1] points here
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| . | / | a | . | o | u | t |\0 | A | R | G | 1 |\0 | A | R | G | 2 |\0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  ^------Program name---------^   ^---Argument 1--^   ^---Argument 2--^
Interpret this 4 bytes as integer:^-----------^
```

Edit: This is the same as in `/proc/self/cmdline` on Linux.

###### argv -> Input mapping

This is how it works on my machine with bash. Probably different on other machines.

```
./myProgram '' '' '' '' # Read as 0x00000000 (4 times a terminating 0 character)
./myProgram ' ' '' ''   # Read as 0x00000020 (0x20 is the ASCII value of ' ')
./myProgram '' ' ' ''   # Read as 0x00002000 (2 times 0 byte, ' ', 0 byte)
./myProgram ' ' ' '     # Read as 0x00200020 (0 byte, ' ', 0 byte, ' ')
./myProgram ' ' '2'     # Read as 0x00320020 (0 byte, '2', 0 byte, ' ')
./myProgram '1234'      # Read as 0x34333231 ('4', '3', '2', '1')
```

However, this will not work

```
# Will not be read as Read 0x00200020, what you might expected, but as 0x00002020.
./myProgram "$(echo -e ' \x00  ')" '' '' '' 
# (note, bash just ignores the \x00 altogether, but it wouldn't work anyway).
```

###### Example Program

Lets say the task is to double a number. Can i do this?:

```
main(int a, char **argv)
{
  int d = *(int*)argv[1]; //<-- Is this allowed?
  printf("%d",d*2);
}
```

Or in a more golfed version: `main(a,v)int **v;{printf("%d",2**v[1]);}`, which is shorter than `main(a,v)int **v;{printf("%d",2*atoi(v[1]));}` which reads `argv[1]` as a ASCII string.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, it is just a matter of interpretation.
No, this is not best practice for real-life applications but *who cares* about sensible programming when codegolfing anyways?

> ```c
> main(int a, char **argv)
> {
>   int d = *(int*)argv[1]; //<-- Is this allowed?
> ```

I do not program in C, but I wonder whether a typecast (I suppose) is really necessary.
Could you not just as well write:

```c
main(int a, int **argv)
```

Comment: To the second part: This works as well. Note that this was also included in the Question: `main(a,v)int **v;{....}`, which is a even shorter form than `main(int a,int **v){....}`. In C, the default type is `int` this is why declarations that don't specify a explicit type (such as `auto`, `static`, no return type, arguments without type) are of type `int`. This is why `main(a,v)int **v;{....}` sets the return type of `main` to `int` as well as the type of `a` to `int`. (This isn't legal C-Code anymore, it was used in pre-ANSI times. But it is shorter and still works on many systems).

Answer (score 0):

## No

AFAIK, this isn't a natural way to take input in the aforementioned languages (or any language that I know of). Surely a (full) program shouldn't need another program to generate the proper input format?

Comment: "Surely a program shouldn't need another program to generate the proper input format?" Writing or reading from a specific address is allowed. Or from a register. Or sometimes only functions are posted without any way to start the program. So the answer this "question" is: No, you may need a program to generate the correct input.

Comment: I don't think that's a good general principle, for example we allow length prefixed input or input as byte values both of which would require a second program to generate the input