# Do function submissions have to be reusable?

Tags: discussion, code-golf, policy

Simple question: if I answer a code golf with a function (*for a task which is supposed to terminate*), does the function actually have to be reusable? Or could it, say, modify some globals which break the function when called again?

(Note that this is *not* about whether functions may modify their inputs. I'm assuming that for each subsequent use the function is called with fresh copies of their arguments.)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## Yes, functions have to be reusable arbitrarily often

That's the point of functions in the first place. If you want to break your environment, answer with a full program.

By "reusable" I mean that the function still complies with all the rules of the spec after it's already been used. It doesn't necessarily have to behave identically if the spec gives some leeway in certain points.

Comment: +1 from me. This is in line with the reasoning for disallowing breaking errors in functions [in this accepted consenus](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4781/8478).

Comment: Does this imply that global variables that are modified within the function and are not reset at the end/beginning are against the rules? If so, I (and presumably many C golfers) have a lot of newly invalid answers.

Comment: @BrainSteel Well if the function requires those global variables to be reset to work, then yes, that would be against these rules. In fact, this doesn't just imply it, this is the main purpose of this question/answer. However, there is no such thing as "newly invalid". Obviously, we won't apply a consensus like this retroactively.

Answer (score 0):

## No, functions may break after use

As long as the function completes successfully once, that's fine, just like with programs.

Comment: -1 from me. (can't vote)

Answer (score -9):

## Yes, functions have to be reusable arbitrarily often and behave exactly identically

This is essentially the same [as this answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4940/8478) but it requires that subsequent calls of the function are 100% indistinguishable, even if the spec leaves some leeway in behaviour.

(Note that in the case of random challenges, the randomness and its distribution are part of the behaviour.)

Comment: -1 from me. This seems unnecessarily strict. I think complying with the spec should be all that's required, and might leave some rather clever golfing tricks.

Comment: This clashes with challenges that require random outputs.

Comment: @xnor I would consider the randomness part of the behaviour.

Comment: So would this be a restriction against self-modifying functions?