# Function not that directly used allowed?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

In [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161797/76323), the function is defined as

```
With(Math)f=(a,b,c,d)=>...    (1)
```

However, `f` is not used in the function, so it seems fine to write

```
With(Math)(a,b,c,d)=>...
```

(the latter one's return value is also the function)

The point is that, you can't write

```
f = With(Math)(a,b,c,d)=>...
```

You either write (1) or

```
f = eval('With(Math)(a,b,c,d)=>...')
```

to make f be the function. Is that allowed?

Comment: It looks like `With(Math)` is just an import and not part of the function itself.

Comment: Seems like between [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9032/42963) and [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7615/42963), you have your answer.

Comment: Are you asking about an anonymous function?

Comment: ```Thus, from math import* is not valid, but from math import*;gcd is.``` seems shows that it's allowed

Comment: An extra problem comes: Do I have to always have extra edit from tio template?