# Is function returned by first invoke of a currying function submission required to be reusable?

Tags: discussion, policy

As per past [discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4939/do-function-submissions-have-to-be-reusable), function submissions should be reusable. And, currying function may be a valid submission.

Consider a challenge which require 2 inputs `x`, and, `y`. A currying function submission may be `f = λ x: (initial_global(); λ y: more_codes_about(x, y))`, and it should be used as `f(x)(y)`. Though `f` is reusable, `g = f(x)` is not (due to failed to initialize global values). Is this a valid submission? Or, in the other word, is function `g = f(x)` required to be reusable?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?  It seems like this flows pretty naturally from the provided links.

Comment: @HatWizard Really? I don't know. `f` needs to be reusable. I wouldn't necessarily expect `g = f(1); g(4); g(5)` to be valid, just `f(1)(4); f(1)(5)`, since `f` is the actual submission. That said, an argument for requiring intermediate functions to be reusable could certainly be made, but I wouldn't say it's clear from rules we already have. I think this is a good question.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I had made an edit on the example. fell free to edit it anyway if it is not such clear.

Comment: The key here is "function submissions".  We don't require that every function in your code is reusable, but rather that your *submission* (which is a function) is reusable.

Comment: seems there was discussion about whether `t=f(4);t(5)` support is necessary

Answer (score 18):

### Only the first function need be reusable

I'd say this for the following reasons:

**Disadvantage to functional languages**

Suppose that there is a challenge to print two numbers, and I submitted the following code in F#:

```
let f x y =
 printfn "x: %i y: %i" x y
```

[F# would implicitly curry this](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/currying/), so to comply it would have to be re-written into something like:

```
let g y = 
 printfn "y: %i" y

let f x =
 printf "x: %i " x
 g
```

Which is a disadvantage to F# (and I'm assuming other functional languages!)

**It's the submitted function itself that's important**

Martin Ender said this too in his comment.

When I look at a submission like:

```
let f x y =
 printfn "x: %i y: %i" x y
```

I'm more looking at if *this block of code* is reusable, rather than *the individual functions curried in this code*. I would expect that the code function be reusable, but not every function implicitly defined in it. The actual submission is what's important.

**It's not a very interesting rule**

The rules are (mainly) there to keep challenges open and interesting. It means that [I can't hard-code a solution](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1063/78954) to a puzzle, because that would make things too easy and dull.

With this restriction I cannot see how it would make things more interesting. To me it would be a superfluous rule that's just there to be followed, and doesn't add anything to the site.

Comment: In pure functional languages all functions are reusable anyway.

Comment: (however: good point. It's not clear what exactly should a partially applied function do)

Answer (score -4):

## It can even be just currying-like

E.g. this is a valid dividing function in C++:

```
#define f(x)x/
```

Called by `f(x)(y)`