# Can a language's True/False be used in place of their values in a sequence?

Tags: discussion, policy

I'm asking this to find a consensus on whether it's okay for an answer to use `True` or `False` in place of the language's corresponding integer values -- as output in a sequence, for example.

So if the challenge is to output the Fibonacci sequence forever, and your output is

```
False, True, True, 2, 3, 5, 8, ...
```

and `False==0` and `True==1` in the language, then this would be acceptable. This is the case for Python. Some languages use `-1` for `True`, so whatever the language uses for the Boolean value is the value that it may be substituted for.

So what do you think? I think it makes sense to allow it. I know there are already answers doing this, but I don't remember where.

Comment: I think this is more a question of "Can I use values of different types that are equal?".  Other "related" questions would be "Could I return a list of integers and BigIntegers?" or "Can I return a list of characters and strings?"  or "Can I return a list of stringified integers and normal integers?"

Comment: IMO [this is relevant here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9501/40695) true/false is not a number and it's trivial to convert them in most languages.