# Can you mix an Esolang with HTML?

Tags: discussion

I've seen tons of Javascript + HTML answers, however... I was wondering if it's okay to compete in a graphical-output challenge such as: [Use 16 colors while writing Hey! 4 times](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85047/use-16-colors-while-writing-hey-4-times)

Using an 05AB1E answer like this:

## [05AB1E/HTML5](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 63 bytes

```
17F"Hey!"N<4%èžz<N÷300+h"<x style='color:#ÿ;'>ÿ</x>"}})¦J"'"'":
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f0NxNySO1UlHJz8ZE9fCKo/uqbPwObzc2MNDOULKpUCguqcxJtVVPzs/JL7JSPrzfWt3u8H4b/Qo7pdpazUPLvJTUgdDq/38A)

---

Should this be allowed? Or simply because it isn't a native function to render HTML in 05AB1E should it not be allowed?

Comment: I mean, it's basically a transpiler, I think it makes sense. However, it can't be likened to Javascript + HTML as you are not running the output of the Javascript, for example, through HTML.

Comment: @Okx yeah, that's a better way of explaining it.

Comment: Write an interpreter that does the transpiling in one step, and you're fine

Comment: @StepHen yeah, but seeing as that's theoretically trivial, do we need to write a transpiler, or should we allow any language to compete using HTML for graphical output?

Comment: The current JavaScript + HTML answers are putting code in two different places, not using the output from one interpreter as the input for another.

Comment: @StepHen yes, I'm not arguing that they're the same. Take for example if TIO had a built-in for "render output as HTML", would that count or would it not? And if that would count, would just stating that, "theoretically, when this HTML5 is executed by a browser, you'd get this: [image]", be okay?

Comment: [Please see this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9501/40695)

Comment: I'd consider `escript osabie test.abe | python -e "import webbrowser; webbrowser.open('data:text/html,'+input())"` a valid interpreter...

Answer (score 14):

For most graphical output challenges, outputting HTML is ok. It's the same as a program outputting a bunch of data and saying "save this as a GIF/BMP/etc." The confusion for this challenge is the wording: *Must be output in STDOUT or the primary colour text output of your language.* 05AB1E has no form of color output so the OP's statement doesn't apply. You should ask the OP if your form of output is allowed for that challenge.

Answer (score 3):

*Theoretically* isn't good enough (such as a theoretical TIO built-in). An interpreter [has to exist at the time of the question being posted](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10226/34718). So if there isn't currently an existing way to run/render such code/output, then it shouldn't be allowed.

> Have a publicly available interpreter / compiler before² the question was posted, unless explicitly allowed by the question.

Comment: So, you're saying that if Dennis actually added a built-in HTML rendering flag into TIO, then it'd be valid? Not asking for one, just trying to feel out where the line is here.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn yes, but also note the no-competing rule was removed, although this would be in the realm of a standard loophole imo