# Are Vim script solutions that does not print the output but starts a vim session with output legal?

Tags: discussion, answers, rules

I wrote [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59645/39442) answer in [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/59464/print-like-this) challenge using *Vim script*. I think I was really creative and got very proud of my solution.

But I am not so sure if this is legal because this program does not print its output to `stdout` but opens a *Vim* session with the output of the program.

This command will run the *Vim script* program I posted:

```
$ echo "This is a test line!" | vim - -c 'nm Q vEUWvEuWQ|norm Q'
```

This will open up Vim displaying this:

```
THIS is A test LINE!
~
~
~
~
~
```

I personally think that this is legal because it does display the correct solution but I am not sure if it counts because the result is displayed within *Vim* and not printed to `stdout`.

I am new to codegolf so I would like to hear from you if I can post more solutions like this to other programs.

Comment: Well, even if it's not, you can write a language called—I don't know—vimgolf? whose interpreter is the bash script `out=$(mktemp) ; vim - -c "$(<"$1")"'<Esc><Esc><Esc>:wq "$out"<CR>' ; cat "$out" ; rm "$out"`! That should solve your problem for future challenges.

Comment: Never thought of that! :)

Answer (score 6):

I would personally consider it valid. However, when in doubt, you should always ask the question writer by commenting on the question. Although there are [set defaults](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) for inputs and output formats, what the question writer says will overwrite these defaults.