# Machine code Input/Output defaults

Tags: discussion, policy, code-golf, defaults

We already have a [question about default I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) for general [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) submissions. However, entries in machine code have different built-in I/O capabilities from entries in high-level languages. Should they be allowed by default to input/output differently?

In this question, consider a machine code *function* to be a program that includes a `ret`urn or similar command. (Classifying machine code entries into programs vs. functions is a separate issue; if you disagree, respond in comments.)

The current consensus is that functions and full programs may do I/O using the same methods, but just in case that changes, I'm making a distinction.
Some options for input and output (to be considered separately):

- Through any port
- Through a specified port
- In any register
- In a specified register (e.g. the accumulator)
- Using cdecl/stdcall conventions (thanks, @feersum)

I was inspired to ask this question by [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62775/39328) to the Truth Machine catalog, which uses the single data bus on a Motorola MC14500 microcontroller as I/O. The OP ruled that valid, but we should have defaults for the future.

Comment: Writing an answer as a function in x86 assembly is something I've been intending to try soon. In that case there are well-defined protocols for receiving and returning parameters (cdecl or stdcall).

Comment: What do you mean by *port*?

Comment: @PeterTaylor [Port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_port_%28hardware%29) and [port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O).

Comment: Maybe we should use stack (like functions is c do) when using systems that are capable for that?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think we should allow different IO methods for programs written in machine code or assembler. Instead I think we should allow some new input methods for **all** languages.

If we can use functions in languages like C, we sould be able to use them also in assembly. Therefore I think that **we should allow programs to take parameters and return output through the stack**.

Some platforms doesn't have a stack by default, so we should find alternative approach. Let's look at the x86 architecture. There used to be thing called BIOS. When DOS calls a BIOS function, it uses registers to pass arguments and get return values. I think that similarly **we should allow programs to take arguments in registers and return values using them**. Value in register can be either input/output value or pointer to it (e.g. pointer to C-style string).

That kind of functions should end with `ret` (or similar) statement.

Comment: Just write your code and put "Inline Assembly" (replace Assembly with FASM / TASM / NAMS etc.) in the answer header. It'll be valid for every challenge that allows functions. Standard would be to provide a ptr to a struct to the function and modify it in place. Standalone-assembly can just use invoke to access standard included files available in all major assemblers. (I.e. Assembly has absolutely no disadvantage against higher languages per se). :-)