# Is this an acceptable way to shave a byte in ES6?

Tags: discussion, policy, answers

Say there's a challenge with two inputs. Can we submit a function signature like this?

```
a=>b=>...
```

Instead of

```
(a,b)=>...
```

The function then becomes callable as `f(a)(b)` instead of `f(a,b)`, if we provide example usage. Is this considered acceptable, or should it be added to "standard loopholes"?

Comment: I'm really tempted to say "morally, no", but I don't have any actual argument against it.

Comment: It... feels wrong, but I don't know why. >_>

Comment: It should be fine, but don't think you can write _actual_ code like this... ;)

Comment: It is only *shorter* for dyadic functions.

Comment: We don't have any rules against currying, so I don't see why not

Comment: Haskell does this all the time, _every_ function has only one argument. So of course it should be allowed for ES6, too.

Comment: [I've added a corresponding answer to the list of admissible I/O methods](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8427/8478) so people don't have to know about yet another meta post.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Well, yes.

You just have to specify how to call it in your answer. It's no different than a submission that expects a certain type of input input (command line args vs. STDIN, for example).

Comment: As odd as that kind of function definition feels, I think you're right.

Answer (score -1):

### No.

This is just shifting work to the caller. Taking that to the nth degree, can't you just submit `c=>c()` to every challenge, explaining that your function needs you to call it with the argument `z=>...insert actual code here...`?

I don't see any reason why the conventions of function calling in Haskell should affect the conventions of function calling in Javascript.

Answer (score -14):

## No

My reasoning is that the output is wrong.

If the challenge was:

> Take two integers `a` and `b` and output the sum of `a` and `b`.

and your answer was:

```
a=>b=>a+b
```

then your answer is in the form of a function (`a=>...`), but the output of this function is another function instead of *"the sum of `a` and `b`"*.

Comment: Does it return a function if you call it like `f(a)(b)`?

Comment: I disagree. You imply that there is a strict way of calling a javascript function; when the code is used in that way, then _of course_ you'll end up with a function.

Comment: I disagree. If you know lambda calculus, you know that `\xy.xy` is the same as `\x.\y.xy`. (If you don't: basically, chaining functions as `a=>b=>` is the same as `(a,b)=>`).

Comment: @AlexA. No, it would return the sum when called like `f(a)(b)`, but note that you are actually calling the outer and the **inner** function which seemed like processing outside of the solution to me. If your answer is the outer function, I feel like you should only be allowed to call the outer function.

Comment: I think calling it like `f(a)(b)` is reasonable so long as its stated that it should be called that way.

Comment: As nimi noted in a comment on the question, this would actually disallow function submissions in languages like Haskell for any problem that takes multiple arguments, since any multi-argument function is actually a curried single-argument function there.