# Are multi-language submissions allowed?

Tags: support, code-golf, answers

I'm not talking about,

> Here's a part of a solution in CJam, and here's the other half in Javalanguage, you figure it out

I'm talking about,

> my language is really simplistic and can't read more than a byte of stdin at a time, so here's a `bash` helper script which reads input, writes it to a known filename and then executes my langauge's interpreter which solves the task using said file

My instinct is that this is either a loophole of some sort, or will be considered simply a needlessly wordy `bash` answer, because the interpreter command is essentially just another `coreutil`, for all the rules care (even though that isn't the case).

I'm not asking whether the bytes in the helper script are counted; obviously, they are.

I can't tell if this is explicitly discouraged, and I don't plan on answering this way any time soon (I'll fix the language first).

Comment: If your language's simplest method of input is files, just use a file as input. I'm fairly certain that's an allowed default [citation-needed].

Comment: It seems the default is either stdin or command line args, never files

Comment: @tac Unless explicitly said otherwise in a challenge, you can use a language's closest alternative to STDIN in lieu of STDIN itself.

Comment: @AlexA. that should probably be an answer :D

Comment: @tac And now it is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Regarding I/O

Programs don't need to read specifically from STDIN since not all languages have a concept of STDIN. That's why we say that a program can read from STDIN *or the language's closest alternative*. It's a little vague, but it basically just means that if your language doesn't have a concept of STDIN, use whatever natural input method most closely resembles STDIN.

Also, if your language can only read from a file, note that reading from a file is currently one of our [default code golf input formats](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2452/20469).

#### On multiple languages

I would call what you described "Bash + SuperCoolLang1000," where the latter is obviously replaced by your language's name. In that case the byte count would be the byte count of the Bash driver program + the byte count of your language's program that does the work.

It may be easier to define Bash + SuperCoolLang1000 as a new language, which is not uncommon so long as there's a specific interpreter for it available, or make the Bash wrapper part of the language itself.