# Is it acceptable to take input in two different formats?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

This isn't an issue yet, but I could see it become one sometime soon. Can I take input in two, or even more, separate formats, provided they're both [reasonable formats](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)? For example, let's say one input was from the user over STDIN and another was a command line argument. If I made that clear in my post would that be acceptable?

Comment: This is [already covered in your linked post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5415/3808).

Comment: @Doorknob Oh wow, well now I feel silly. Oh well, at least I have the answer now. Thanks!