# Is Prolog's REPL unification mechanism allowed for multiple outputs?

Tags: discussion

This meta-question is inspired by [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/78448/count-up-folks?noredirect=1#comment191804_78448), which basically asks to count from 1 to N. However this is a question that bothers me in a lot of challenges which have those “iterative”/“print all X such that” kind of outputs.

So keeping as an example this challenge of counting from 1 to N, a possible solution in Prolog is to write a predicate which will unify a variable with an integer. Then, Prolog's backtracking mechanism makes it so that we can ask all possible values that make this predicate true.

For instance in this example, I could write a predicate `a(N,I)`which unifies `I` with an integer between 1 and `N`. Calling it would give this result:

```
?- a(5,I).
I = 1
```

However now instead of terminating, Prolog's REPL halts: if I type `;` (logical or), it will give me a second answer:

```
I = 2
```

I can keep doing this until it finds no more solution:

```
I = 3 ;
I = 4 ;
I = 5
```

And now it has terminated.

Is this a fair way of returning/printing outputs? Note that it is possible to fill a list with all those unifications and return that list using `findall`, but this is obviously longer.

*This question also applies for languages that work on Prolog (e.g. Brachylog) or that have a similar mechanism in their REPL (e.g. ?)*

Comment: Seems kinda like a Python generator function, with consecutive calls, and the poilcy there is that the function should give in whole the required output [citation needed].

Answer (score 3):

## Yes, that is allowed.

It is almost the same as a list, in the sense that it doesn't output each term individually automatically.

Like cat pointed out, this is a lot like a python generator, which is an acceptable output format as far as I know.

Comment: No, Python generators are lazy magical black boxes -- to get all their output at once, you need `[next(my_func()) for i in range(x)]` or so

Comment: @cat but I still think it is a valid output format?

Comment: [Here's a source on allowing lists to be output as generators](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10753/62131). I had Prolog in mind when I wrote it. Note that this isn't really connected with REPLs; you can do the same generator→list conversion from within code using `findall`.