# Is Ans considered a valid form of input for TI-BASIC?

Tags: discussion

We haven't reached a complete consensus on whether or not `Ans` is permitted as a valid input format for TI-BASIC.

We have [this answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/8580#8580) on "Default for Code Golf: Input/Output methods" with a slim majority support for its use, but I recently posted an answer to [Approximation of e](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/82604/approximation-of-e) which used `Ans` as input, receiving a large amount of dispute over the matter.

The previous meta post answer also cites [another TI answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/73920/golf-the-x%E1%B5%97%CA%B0-root-of-x/73977#73977) using `Ans` that was questioned heavily. Though that should prohibit the use of `Ans`, some have stated that `Ans` has historically been used without issue.

So is `Ans` permitted as a valid form of input, or not?

Comment: As you stated, there is already an answer on the I/O methods post. That answer lacks significant support to be considered consensus, so it's not an acceptable method.

Answer (score 4):

## Yes, it is a valid form of input

While TI-BASIC does not come with any sort of function, they can be faked. I use this approach often when making a program that is repeated multiple times by a parent program. By using the value of `Ans`, one can transform `Ans` into another value and leave it as `Ans`. Say we wanted to write a "function" that takes the sign of the number (not golfing, here)

```
PRGM:SGN
Ans→A
If A<0:-1
If A=0:0
If A>0:1
```

Then, from a parent program:

```
PRGM:PARENT
ClrHome
Input "NUMBER=",B
B:prgmSGN
Output(2,1,"Sign of B=
Output(2,11,Ans
```

As such, it is often more *useful* to other programs to take input in the form of `Ans`. While it is not a true function, it is the closest TI-BASIC can get. Therefore, being a "function", `Ans` should be valid input.

Comment: Please refrain from answering obvious duplicate questions, especially with incorrect answers. It's clear from the dupe target that `Ans` is not an acceptable form of input.

Comment: [The answer on the dupe target](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8580/45941) has +14/-10. The rule is net +5 and at least twice as many upvotes as downvotes to be a valid form of input. It fails on both criteria. You may personally think that it is a valid form of input, but it is clear that the community disagrees.

Comment: @Mego Alright, what would happen if somebody posted an answer "No, last expression is not valid input." It would likely have something like a +10/-14, judging from the votes on the dupe target. Still no clear consensus, yet you clearly think there is some compelling reason to go the other way.

Comment: The defaults post is a whitelist. By community consensus, if an I/O method does not fulfill the requirements, it is not valid. Had it been created as a blacklist (like the standard loopholes post), the situation would be different.

Comment: @Mego Conceded.