# Are we allowed to copy the output of the code to the clipboard?

Tags: discussion, output

Asking for a friend...

---

For ["Hello, World!"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world), you can save an extra 1 byte by using `copy("Hello, World")`. However, I am confused on if it's allowed for your output to be the clipboard.

The question's rules say:

> - The program must take no input, and print `Hello, World!` to STDOUT (this exact byte stream, including capitalization and punctuation) plus an optional trailing newline, and nothing else.
> - The program must not write anything to STDERR.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### In general

I've proposed [Programs may write output to the clipboard](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11661/12012) yesterday and it has received a mixed response (**+2/-4**) so far. At this point, writing to the clipboard is not a valid form of output by default, and it might very well never become one.

#### Regarding [“Hello, World!”](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55422/12012)

The challenge states very clearly that the output must be printed to STDOUT, so whatever the default may be, the clipboard is not a valid output format for this challenge.