# Clarification of global variables as "arguments"

Tags: discussion

Say language X supports functions, but input must be done through one of the predefined global variables (all initialized to zero). Can I consider this a use of an argument? Similarly can I use this global variable (or another) as an "output argument". I believe the [standards](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/46918) are unclear on this.

Comment: This should be a comment or a proposed answer on [this question](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/46918), rather than a separate question.

Comment: The standards are *not* unclear on this. Functions are allowed, but you still have to receive input via allowed methods. If you think an exception should be made for a particular language, you should propose it and let the community vote on it.