# Can we expect out arguments to be allocated?

Tags: discussion, output

According to [this consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4942) in the default allowed inputs thread, functions may output by writing to an out argument.

When outputting an array in languages like C/C++, where arrays are pointers to locations in memory, can we assume the memory at the output location to have been allocated and to be of a sufficient size to output the complete answer, or must the memory be allocated in the code?

Below are some example functions in C that output by modifying their parameters; please consider each case, and state which cases you'd consider acceptable.

```
// Fixed size
void one_to_ten(int*o){
    for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
        o[i-1]=i;
}

// Output size is a function of input size
void mul_table(int*o,int*a,int m,int*b,int n){
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
            o[i*n+j]=a[i]*b[j];
 }

// Size of output is given
void roll_dice(int*res, int n){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        res[n]=rand()%6+1;
}

// Output has a variable size and a defined maximum size
void scramble(int*o, int seed){
    srand(seed);
    int r;
    for(int i=0; (r=rand())&&i<128; i++)
        o[i]=r;
}
```

Comment: The range of where should be defined the arg is 0..9 so the array in the arg would be int a[n]; with n>=10

Comment: @RosLuP I'm not sure if I understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 2):

## You can at least assume the output buffer is **enough**

Anyway even GCC doesn't(or can't) check it when doing `memcpy`

Comment: Strictly speaking, GCC never does `memcpy` in a way you're talking about: it just inserts call to library or syscall.