# What counts as "output" in SQL?

Tags: discussion

Some of the site's questions rule that something must (or must not) be printed to the output. My question is, in the case of SQL, what really is the output?

The `select` command returns result-sets, which can be a 1x1 array of "string".
The `print` command, as defined in a specific implementation (sql server), returns a string to the user.

So `select 'Hello world!'` and `print 'Hello world!'` are both valid commands that return the same string to the user, albeit in different places.

So, which of these are considered "printing" in terms of golf SE? Could it be both?

Comment: I'd think either would be allowed, like how there's `alert`, `print`, and `console.log` for JS.

Comment: When we decide on an answer it goes here. https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods There's an INPUT case for SQL but no OUTPUT case.

Comment: Are you talking about MSSQL, T-SQL, MySQL/MariaBD, SQLite, PostgreSQL or some other?

Comment: I personally use mssql/tsql, but I guess such choice would be present in other dbmss too.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis MySQL doesn't support the `print` statement. The closest you have is `SELECT 'Hello world!' as ''` (just `SELECT 'Hello world!'` works but shows the text twice, once on the column name and once on the content). Or `\! echo 'Hello world!';` but that's just calling the `echo` statement from the console (https://stackoverflow.com/a/61375812/).

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, but that way you will have a leading newline. Why not “`--skip-column-names`, `-N` Do not write column names in results.”? https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwPNY.png

Comment: @manatwork There are rules in place about flags. And I doubt that all SQL implementations (or most) have those flags. Or they do have it, but also have the `print` statement. Also, I doubt that people will be running the scripts directly from the console. They will probably have an online environment to try it, or a website with an SQL IDE, where that option doesn't exist. But, if an answer for MySQL specifies it, why not? Maybe should be part of the rules?

Comment: Also works when running SQL script file. PostgreSQL has “`-t`, `--tuples-only` Turn off printing of column names and result row count footers, etc.”, but have to also use “`-A`, `--no-align` Switches to unaligned output mode.” There your empty alias trick doesn't work. In SQLite there is “`-[no]header` Turn headers on or off.” but the no is the default anyway. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hmjn.png

Answer (score 1):

We have countless examples of highly upvoted answers sending SQL output to either the *results* pane (via `SELECT`) or to the *messages* pane (via `PRINT`), depending on which works the best and is shorter for a particular challenge.

Both are acceptable.

(This uses terminology from MS SQL Management Studio, other platforms/clients likely have equivalents.)

Note other outputs are possible as well, such as outputting graphical results to the [spatial results pane](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211500/70172).

Comment: Could you cross-post this to [Default for Code Golf: Input/Output methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/66833), so the standard consensus rules on that question apply, and we can close this question as a duplicate?

Comment: [Cross posted](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19360/70172)