# Can Whispers programs ignore a final output line?

Tags: discussion, answers, languages

This was first [asked by Leo in the Whispers chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56954559#56954559):

> But I have a general question about Whispers submissions: couldn't we avoid counting the final Output line most of the time? We can consider the rest of the program a function returning the desired output, printing it to the screen with a full program is not generally required for submissions

This seems, to me, as though an edge case of the general I/O formats, so posting an answer over to the [I/O defaults](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) may not allow for appropriate discussion.

For those unfamiliar with Whispers, programs work line-by-line where each line returns a specific value. Lines are "called" by other lines through references in order to get the value from that line. For example, the basic Hello World program:

```
> "Hello, World!"
>> Output 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTkHJIzUnJ19HITy/KCdFUYnLzk7Bv7SkoLREwfD/fwA)

As you can probably figure out, the last line "calls" line **1** and outputs the result.

However, by Leo's argument above, an equally valid program per our I/O rules would be

```
> "Hello, World!"
```

as you could consider this a function which returns the string `"Hello, World!"` when "called" by another line referencing it.

This meets our requirements for a function (it is reusable, lines can be composed with arguments, lines can call other lines etc.), but it definitely isn't a standard function.

Thoughts? Should Whispers programs be allowed to ignore a final `>> Output` line and consider the rest of the program as a function that returns the output?

Comment: The `Hello, world!` challenge doesn't allow functions anyway, so this may not be the best example.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms For the specific *challenge*, it doesn’t really apply. However, I wanted to choose a clear example that anyone would be able to understand and "Hello World" is sort of a quintessential programming example

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Whispers lines are functions and they should follow our rules for functions

Since I was the one posing this question here's my opinion on this.

Each line in Whispers is a function. Most often, these functions take no input, call other functions, and return one output. Calling a function that takes no input is as simple as writing the corresponding line number (in the "Hello, World!" example line 2 calls the function line 1 and outputs the result of that).

A function can take up to two arguments, referred with the identifiers `L` and `R`. We can pass arguments to functions with the infix operator `∘` (only supports one argument) or with constructs like `Each`, `∑`,`∏`,`…` (can use two arguments, special conditions apply).

With lines being functions our defaults for functions apply, including:

- [Functions may output via their return value(s)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2456/62393)
- [Functions may take input via function arguments](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2454/62393)
- [Functions may output via the same methods as full programs](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2457/62393)
- [Functions may take input via the same methods as full programs](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2455/62393)

Combining these, we get that Whispers submissions may take input with the command `Input` or with the `L`/`R` arguments, and may produce output with the command `Output` or with the implicit return value of the main function line.

---

#### Edit

Clarification, since I've seen people confused by this: you cannot just take any Whispers program, remove the first and last line and claim this is now a function. The submitted function needs to really work as a function.

In practice, if your program only produced output via a final `>> Output N` line, it should be enough to remove that and have line N be your function submission (with all other lines being auxiliary functions). Taking input via L/R generally needs bigger changes to your code, your main function will need to use L/R itself, and these values will need to be passed to any auxiliary function working on the input: this will not necessarily be shorter than the original program, and in some cases it may even be impossible to do. As a rule, your function should never refer to lines outside the function itself (this would be similar to taking input from pre-initialized variables).

Example:

```
>> Input
>> 1!
>> Output 2
```

This is a program that prints the factorial of an input number. We can turn it into a function by getting rid of the final output line:

```
>> Input
>> 1!
```

Now our line 2 is the function we are submitting, giving output via its return value. We can also decide to take input via argument L:

```
>> L!
```

And this can be our submission. We can write a full program to test it by calling the function on some input and printing its result to the screen: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fzk7BR/G/nYJnXkFpCReQZ/ioY4YRiOFfWgIUUjD@bwwA).