# Byte counting for BASIC style DATA / READ inputs

Tags: discussion, code-golf, scoring

#### Background

Many BASIC dialects idiomatically use `DATA` and `READ` commands to store and read input data from the source code.  We appear to have [a consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11691/61846) that this form of input is valid in these languages, however we have not formed a consensus on how to score solutions that use this approach.

#### The Question

Given a snippet of the form shown below, how should it be scored?

#### [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), ??? bytes

```vb
DATA 2
DATA 3
DIM primes(4)
FOR i = 1 TO 4
  READ primes(i)
  PRINT primes(i)
NEXT
DATA 5
DATA 7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/38UxxFHBiAtMGXO5ePoqFBRl5qYWa5hocrn5BylkKtgqGCqE@CuYcCkoBLk6usDkMzWBAgFBnn4hSCJ@rhEhELNMIZT5//8A)

Answer (score 1):

## All `Read` Bytes Should Be Scored

Snippets should be split into header, code, and footer sections, with all `DATA` calls in the header and/or footer. All other code will contribute to byte count.

### Example

#### [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 68 bytes

###### Header (not counted)

```
DATA 2
DATA 3
```

###### Code

```
DIM primes(4)
FOR i = 1 TO 4
  READ primes(i)
  PRINT primes(i)
NEXT
```

###### Footer (not counted)

```
DATA 5
DATA 7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7v4hjiqGDEBaaM/7t4@ioUFGXmphZrmGhyufkHKWQq2CoYKoT4K5hwKSgEuTq6wOQzNYECAUGefiFIIn6uESEQI00hRpr/BwA)

Comment: I would generally support this approach, as works well with TIO - style online editors, and should be flexible enough to work with most languages in most situations

Answer (score -1):

## All Non-data Bytes Should Be Scored

All Non-data (that is data, not `DATA`) bytes, including all required `DATA` calls, as well as all necessary spaces, newlines, etc.

## Example

#### [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 92 bytes

*Note: all `#` in the below snippet represent points of user input, and do not contribute to the byte count*

```
DATA #
DATA #
DIM primes(4)
FOR i = 1 TO 4
  READ primes(i)
  PRINT primes(i)
NEXT
DATA #
DATA #
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/38UxxFGBC0p6@ioUFGXmphZrmGhyufkHKWQq2CoYKoT4K5hwKSgEuTq6wOQzNYECAUGefiFIIn6uESFcSAb@/w8A)

Comment: I would recommend against this approach, as it does not work well with TIO style editors, variable input lengths, and leaves a large amount of ambiguity around inputs of the form `DATA 1,2,3` - do the commas count? what if commas are not legal in your dialect? how do you handle variable length input?