# When accepting input from STDIN, can it be assumed to terminate with a newline

Tags: discussion

...or I guess more specifically, can I require that input from STDIN (or closest alternative, e.g. TIO) be newline terminated?

Utilising apps like TIO this isn't added, but if using a terminal with `<<<` a newline is appended, it can only be omitted using something like `echo -n ... | script`. I've definitely used either as it suits me, but I don't know if that's appropriate or not.

A specific example of this is [my answer to](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250530/9365) [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/250522/9365) which could save two bytes assuming a newline exists on the input, but would necessitate TIO having an explicit terminating newline.

---

### This has [an answer in the I/O defaults](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24639/78410)

Thanks to [@Bubbler](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler) for clarifying.

My read on this is that you may specify either way as your answer requires.

Comment: I think this case is covered by [this default I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24639/78410). In the challenge, newlines are guaranteed to not appear in the input string, so you can use it as the "sentinel" (which means the input will always be `<input string><newline>` for your program).

Comment: Ok great, so I could just specify in answers for clarity that newline is either required or must be omitted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default for Code Golf: Input/Output methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)

Answer (score 2):

## Use either, specify what's required

This fits with flexible I/O but could be contentious, it's what I feel is the most forgiving and I don't see how this could be abused for any meaningful score reduction, but I could be missing something!