# What's a number?

Tags: discussion, answers, specification

Similar to [What's a string?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/whats-a-string)

If a challenge says that the input will be “a number”, what data types are acceptable?

Obviously, types like `int` and `float` are numeric.

What about strings?  Command-line arguments and stuff read from standard input will naturally be string or sequence-of-char objects, so we'll have to accept string input in those cases.  But do we accept strings as *function* arguments, if the language has dedicated data types for representing numbers?

What about lists of digits, like representing 12345 as `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` (list of digits as numbers) or `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']` (list of digits as char/string)?

**Edit:** No, I don't think this is a duplicate of [Default for Code Golf: Input/Output methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).  That question's answers focus on *where* the input can come from: From command-line arguments, from a file, from a GUI input box, etc.  Whereas my question is about *what type* of input should be acceptable.

Comment: The standard IO formats have a lot to do with what types input can be as well as where it can come from.

Comment: I've posted [an answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18097/76162) to the default IO formats question regarding taking numbers as a string and vice-versa

Comment: Also see [Data type may be standardized](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13217/73111), [Unary string](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16559/73111), [Lists of digits are interchangeable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17167/73111), [Numbers as character codes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18027/73111), [Combination of I/O for the same data type](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5415/73111) and [Functions may take input via the same methods as full programs](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2455/73111)

Comment: Further see [Functions may take input via function arguments](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2454/73111), [Programs may take input from a file](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2452/73111), [Programs may take input via command-line arguments](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2449/73111) and [Programs may take input via STDIN](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2448/73111).

Comment: I would disagree regarding your edit, as for example allowing `stdin` for numeric input implies allowing a conversion to characters.