# User posting answer of an unavailable tool

Tags: discussion, users

I have noticed a user making questionable answers. Here are some examples:

- [In for a bumpy ride](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/167924/-/167933)
- [Concatenating n with n + 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/167818/-/167819)
- [Let's design a digit mosaic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/167337/-/167372)
- [Print the digital root](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97713/-/167251)
- [Simple ASCII Gantt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52400/-/166987)

In all cases, he is purporting to use a tool called `ngn/k` - this raises a
couple of concerns:

1. as his name is `ngn`, he wrote the tool
2. both the page he links to and his similar github page host no software, only
   a readme: https://gitlab.com/n9n/k and https://github.com/ngn/k

to me this is not acceptable - if someone is posting and getting upvotes on
answers, they should be using a publicly available tool, and ideally an open
source one.

Comment: It is publicly available - the full binary is on TryItOnline

Comment: [Here](https://tio.run/#k-ngn) is the link, it's also in the readme you linked.

Comment: It appears not to be open source for the time being, but that doesn't mean ngn would be unwilling to open-source it

Comment: From previous commits of the readme: `I don't make the source code and the binary publicly available at this time`.

Comment: ["Universally testable answer"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2031). ; [What programming languages have been created by PPCG users?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6918)

Comment: The binary can be taken from TIO though ([link to part of binary](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzmxREE/v6BEP1s3Lz1PP1uhRqGiIgVIZqQmpijo5ikYGhiZ/P8PAA)), so you can download and run it to verify the solutions. ngn/k _is_ an implementation of k though, so you can also switch to oK, which has near identical behavior

Comment: @ASCII-only I wouldnt call reverse engineering TIO "downloading"

Comment: Also: Avoid asking more than 1 question in 1 question. You're asking (1) is it ok to use a language you write yourself (2) proprietary languages.

Comment: So "completely unavailable" and "unavailable without paying" are slightly different...

Comment: @StevenPenny sure. but it _does_ mean that the binary is publicly available

Answer (score 9):

ngn/k *is* publicly available: https://tio.run/#k-ngn. You can use it to verify ngn/k answers or – if you know the K language – write your own answers.

There are many programming languages that exist only as an online interpreter. As long as this implementation is not a blackbox (server-side interpreter that doesn't expose the binary) and *remains* available, this is not an issue.

As long as you can reliably verify solutions, that's enough for PPCG. What you can or cannot do with these languages *outside PPCG* is not our concern.