# Template For Challenges

Tags: support, faq

What format is generally good for questions? Is there a good template I can use?

[Return to FAQ index](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1280)

Comment: This post should be displayed as "*Featured on meta*" alongside the Sandbox.

Answer (score 40):

You can follow this format:

---

## Introduction

Briefly describe the challenge. Provide a short background for your challenge. Briefly answer the following questions for your readers.

- Why is this challenge interesting?
- Did you create the challenge? Give credit and provide links to your sources.

A short paragraph will work just fine here. We do not need a book.

## Challenge

Describe your challenge in complete detail. The following must be present in any challenge.

- A complete description of all inputs
- A complete description of all outputs
- A complete description of how input and output are related

Answer the following questions for your readers.

- Are there any corner cases? Is it clear how they should be handled?
- How will the winner of the challenge will be determined?
- Is it clear how all submissions will be scored?

Avoid burying the important details of your challenge in a mound of unimportant details. Be concise. Include what needs to be included.

## Example Input and Output

Provide at least one example input and output. Make sure they match your own description of what the input should look like.

Input:

> This is an example input

Output:

> This is an example output

...

---

### ***Copy and paste the following Markdown***

```
# Introduction

Briefly describe the challenge. Provide a short background for your challenge. Briefly answer the following questions for your readers.

 - Why is this challenge interesting?
 - Did you create the challenge? Give credit and provide links to your sources.

A short paragraph will work just fine here. We do not need a book.

# Challenge

Describe your challenge in complete detail. The following must be present in any challenge.

 - A complete description of all inputs
 - A complete description of all outputs
 - A complete description of how input and output are related

Answer the following questions for your readers.

 - Are there any corner cases? Is it clear how they should be handled?
 - How will the winner of the challenge will be determined? 
 - Is it clear how all submissions will be scored?

Avoid burying the important details of your challenge in a mound of unimportant details. Be concise. Include what needs to be included.

# Example Input and Output

Provide at least one example input and output. Make sure they match your own description of what the input should look like.

Input:

> This is an example input

Output:

> This is an example output

...
```

Comment: If your challenge is just mapping values to new values in some way, your test cases should probably be in the format `1 -> 5`, `2 -> 8`, `10 -> 240`, etc.