# New First-Time Asker Dialog

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, asking-questions, new-users

**This revision has been submitted to the devs to push the change, so unless there are any critical issues, this is the final version and I will not be modifying it anymore.**

---

(I have cut down the post body to make the request clearer for reviewers; you can view the revision history for the original question.)

The current modal that appears for someone asking for the first time doesn't really contain helpful information for our site; however, we can change it.

After deliberating with the community, I formally [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) the following.

---

Change the text before the note about searching the site for duplicates to:

> [Welcome to Code Golf & Coding Challenges!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20862) We host recreational coding challenges & related questions including code golf, fastest code and code golfing tips. All challenges must have an [**objective** scoring criterion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305/what-makes-winning-criteria-objective), and should [avoid these listed points](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8047). 
>  **Questions about help with general programming-related issues are off-topic here and will be closed.** 
> Please post your challenge as a draft to our [Sandbox for Proposed Challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) for a few days first for feedback. Doing so allows you to correct issues you might otherwise miss before posting to the main site.

---

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Change the text *after* the aforementioned note to:

> The following bullet points only apply to non-challenge questions

---

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Remove** the third bullet point.

Comment: There's a big problem. You can't customize the big **1 2 3** part, at least not from what the post says. You can only insert information in a paragraph above the existing text.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Yes, but we can disable the 3rd part from what I've been told, and all we can do is do our best to clarify in the paragraph before it.

Comment: Just append "Ignore everything below this".

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20624/66833)

Comment: This is just a comment, but can we add a link to the basic question template?

Comment: @Ausername Where is that?

Comment: @hyper-neutrino [Template for Challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1511/template-for-challenges). It's a good general resource, but I don;t think its a necessary thing to add

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Ah, thanks. That's in the sidebar so we can probably point them there and trim even more content out, I think.

Comment: Related: [MSE post announcing the introduction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513), which specifies what you can and cannot change. (You cannot change anything from "Before you post," and down)

Comment: @Peilonrayz Thanks for the info; I'll keep that in mind!

Comment: A weird idea -- can we put enough empty lines after our text so that the irrelevant default text is no longer visible?

Comment: @xnor Testing shows that that would make the modal scrollable which is more confusing, sadly :( Also, the "Start Writing" button would disappear too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yaakov kindly updated this to include the information you wished. It'd require a bigger change to make it possible to get rid of the bullet points but I'll discuss internally about whether that's something we want to request. I know this would be great for y'all but with the number of devs we have currently, it'd be a decision of whether this was higher priority than other things - so we can discuss internally but I'm not making any promises.

[image: Screenshot of the new asking a good question modal with the text as described in the question.]

Answer (score 8):

### Asking a good question

This is a site for competitive coding enthusiasts. We host coding challenges, such as [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info), and related questions, such as golfing tips. We require that all new challenges have an **objective** scoring criterion, so the winner can be appropriately and fairly chosen. **Questions about help with general programming-related issues are off-topic here** - those belong on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

We suggest you post your challenge draft to our [Sandbox for Proposed Challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) before posting it to main, in order to help find out if it's a duplicate, clear up any ambiguities or otherwise get feedback. Doing so allows you to correct potential issues before actually posting the challenge.

Be aware that the two bullet points below are not generally relevant to our site - we're simply unable to change them.

---

Thoughts? This may be a little long (and I can cut down the paragraph about the Sandbox if so), and the bit about irrelevance seems odd.

Changed the wording slightly to fit [hyper-neutrino's answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/23489/66833) better, as that's the standard site terminology.

Changed some wordings thanks to [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo)'s [suggestion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23485/new-first-time-asker-dialog/23488?noredirect=1#comment74384_23488)

Comment: I don't believe those two options are available for us to change, unfortunately. At least, assuming I interpreted Catija correctly. I will ask again but I doubt it, I think the best they can do is get rid of the third point.

Comment: For point 1., "challenge" and "problem" are close enough that it doesn't matter much. So the only significant issue is 2.  All I can suggest is preceding it with a note saying that "research" in point 2. really means "the scoring criteria".

Comment: @RayButterworth I mainly included the bullets as more of a hopeful thing. The "meat" of the suggestion is the text above the "Before you post, ..."

Comment: It might be a good idea to add that the three last bullets aren't relevant to CGCC. You might also want to add that [tag:tips] questions are on-topic.

Comment: @user Good point, edited

Comment: A couple of suggestions, in case you want to incorporate them: "criteria" should be "criterion". "Doing so makes it significantly simpler": I would say something more explicit, such as "Doing so allows you to correct potential issues before actually posting the challenge"

Comment: @LuisMendo That's a significantly better way of putting it, I;ve edited that in :)

Comment: 'This is a site for competitive coding enthusiasts' no it isn't. Code golf is not competitive programming and this will only confuse people.

Comment: @rak1507 Code golf *is* competitive coding - we compete to create the shortest code. Additionally, this is more or less standard terminology used to describe the site, see the welcome page, the help center, the info box etc.

Comment: Unfortunately competitive coding or competitive programming is already an established term that means something very different, and I think terms should be unambiguous to avoid any potential confusion.

Comment: The sentence should be "Be aware that the [three] bullet points below ...".

Comment: @Peilonrayz According to hyper (see the question body), we're able to disable the third bullet point (but only the third one), so this answer assumes that we're disabling it

Answer (score 4):

To add to caird coinheringaahing's version, since we have decided to allow non-challenge questions, I propose the addition of this point in the middle of the current first paragraph and to replace the advisory on Stack Overflow, and splitting the SO point to a new paragraph (or keep it in the first):

> This is a site for competitive coding enthusiasts. We host coding challenges, such as [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info). We require that all new challenges have an **objective** scoring criteria, so the winner can be appropriately and fairly chosen. We also allow code golf or code challenge related questions (such as tips), and a list of acceptable non-challenge questions can be found in [this FAQ](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1723/lets-decide-what-kind-of-non-challenge-questions-we-want-once-and-for-all).

> **Questions about help with general programming-related issues are off-topic here** - those belong on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 3):

## Posting a new challenge

Welcome to Code Golf and Coding Challenges Stack Exchange! This is a site where coding enthusiasts congregate to solve competitive challenges, not a general Q&A site for coding. All challenges must have an objective scoring criterion such that the winner may be fairly chosen. **Questions asking for help with specific coding problems should be posted on Stack Overflow**, although we do allow [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) questions here asking for tips on code golfing.

All challenges not tagged [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) should first be drafted in the [sandbox for proposed challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=active), where feedback can be given. It is recommended to leave ideas there for at least 72 hours.

Once the challenge has been through a week's time in the sandbox, there are several more things to keep in mind:

- Unless your challenge is tagged [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill), it should not be language specific. This excludes participation from certain members and is discouraged.
- Unless the input/output format plays a crucial role in the challenge, [avoid cumbersome I/O formats](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). Forcing certain methods of input or output further takes away from the main task.

Next, make sure to [search](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search) the website to make sure that your challenge has not been posted by someone else.

Once you have performed all of the above tasks, you're ready to post your challenge!

---

#### Meta

Thoughts? Maybe the end part, couldn't think of anything to say.

Comment: "You're ready" suggests you don't need to post in the Sandbox right now. Could you maybe change that?

Comment: @user I have edited it.

Comment: I was talking about the part at the very start of the question, since a first time asker isn't ready if they haven't posted in the Sandbox first.

Comment: @user Sorry for the misunderstanding. Would something along the lines of "Welcome to Code Golf and Coding Challenges Stack Exchange!" be more suitable?

Comment: That sounds good, yeah. Also, saying "a week's time" may discourage people, even if it's a good suggestion. Maybe change that to "at least 72 hours" instead?

Comment: I'm concerned that "coding enthusiasts congregate to solve competitive challenges" will sounds to people like we solve challenges from Leetcode or HackerEarth or similar. how about "coding enthusiasts congregate to create and solve competitive challenges"?

Answer (score 3):

We have a Welcome to CGCC page, we should link it in the popup. Specifically, the section on [Asking](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20862/68942).

I propose adding this paragraph after everything mentioned so far but before the note about ignoring the two bullet points:

> We [welcome](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861) you to Code Golf & Coding Challenges Stack Exchange. The FAQ on [Asking good questions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20862) contains more details and goes more in-depth on advice for asking on this site. By following the advice in this popup and on that FAQ page, we hope that all new users will be able to understand the scope of this site and have a positive first experience with our community.