# Off-topic questions: could we require objective winning criteria?

Tags: feature-request, new-users, winning-criteria

We require that challenges have objective winning criteria, for reasons that have already been covered in various questions (in particular, see the link below). However, we receive many questions that do not have these criteria, and they are really annoying for many reasons.

There have been a few steps taken in an attempt to ensure that new users post challenges that have objective winning criteria, as well as some steps to reduce the number of off-topic questions. These attempts include:

- a new question dialog ([link](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23485/new-first-time-asker-dialog))
- Welcome to Code Golf and Coding Challenges Stack Exchange! ([link](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20861/welcome-to-code-golf-and-coding-challenges-stack-exchange))
- a message on the sidebar
- and probably more.

Unfortunately, however, we still receive many questions that are either:

- blatantly off-topic (mostly general programming questions like those that would be found on Stack Overflow, but sometimes also spam), or
- challenges that are salvageable, but initially lack key details that are required for challenges on this site, notably [objective winning criteria](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8130/why-do-we-have-objective-winning-criteria).

I'd like to propose a solution that could mitigate **both** of these problems:

**Create some sort of automated review system that does not allow questions to be posted *unless* there is at least one objective winning criterion. If no winning criterion is present, then show a dialog containing information about objective winning criteria, as well as a reminder that questions must be coding challenges.**

The dialog could then list all of the objective winning criteria recognized by the community: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge), [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code), [metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metagolf), etc.

Now, here are some pros and cons of such a measure.

### Pros

Those who currently post Stack Overflow-esque programming questions would see a dialog which states that their questions are not welcome on the website, and would instead post their question on Stack Overflow.

New users who are initially unfamiliar would get information on objective winning criteria, and then add an objective winning criterion that they see fit for their question, and said user would not get as many downvotes or comments asking for objective winning criteria.

Established users who simply forgot to add an objective winning criterion would also get a reminder to do so, and would receive less negative feedback with regard to objective winning criteria.

A total block on questions that do not have objective winning criteria would thus reduce the number of unfit questions.

### Cons

Of course, some users will just ignore the dialog and tack on a random objective winning criterion. This is especially true for some spammers; their questions usually come with a bunch of random tags, and my proposed measure would do nothing to prevent their questions from being posted.

Note as well that the implementation of such a measure might not be possible given the rejection of similar measures previously.

### Conclusion

Overall, I think such a measure would be useful to cut down on the number of unfit questions we receive on this website.

Comment: There is also [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20624/66833) - regex based tag warnings are an option, but, after discussing it a bit with SE staff in chat, it was said that they only search for banned patterns, not searching for the *lack* of specific tags