# Where should non-challenge questions go?

Tags: discussion, support, faq

I have a question about programming puzzles or code golf, and it's not a challenge for others to solve. Where should I post it?

[Return to FAQ index](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1280)

Comment: I feel like these questions (including golfing tips) are meta-code-golf questions (I don't mean meta as in this site) but that they are _about_ puzzles or solving puzzles rather than actual puzzle questions, so aren't really on topic for the main site which is why tips are cw'd. My concern is that good on-topic questions will disappear in the noise if too many of those type of questions start showing up.

Comment: I think [alias-member-functions-in-python](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26831/alias-member-functions-in-python) could be asked on SO, but I'm definitely in favour of keeping all the golfing/puzzle stuff on this site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bear in mind that [some questions don't belong on either the main site or the meta site](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Some of these questions can still be asked on [our main **chat room**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte).

- Examples of questions which should **only be asked in chat**:

  - what do you think of my golfing language?

If your question is about PPCG.SE *specifically*, post it on meta.

- Examples that **should** be on meta:

  - proposals of new tags or types of content
  - discussions of policy
  - questions about this community
- Examples that **should not** be on meta:

  - tips for golfing - not specific to this site

If it is a **"list" question**, is specific enough to have focused answers and not so broad that a book could be written to answer it, post it on main and flag for a mod to convert it to Community Wiki. Note that these types of questions are discouraged, and it would be ideal if you could ask your question in a way that doesn't invite answers that are just big lists.

- Examples that **should be CW**:

  - tips for golfing in {language}
  - how can I optimize a golfing language to be shorter?
  - what are some strategies to solve {some type of programming puzzle / challenge}?
  - what important math functions do I need to add to my language's library? which ones are superfluous and don't need to be added?

If it is a question about how to improve an idea you have for a challenge post, post it as an **answer** in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=sandbox).

If it is a narrow question about code golfing, post it to main without flagging for Community Wiki.

- Examples that **should not be CW**:

  - how can I shorten this specific code structure or construct?
  - how can I handle I/O better in my golfing language?
  - who {did some important event} in the history of code golf?

Comment: Maybe we can add the sandbox in the first paragraph, e.g. questions of type "Would this be a good code-challenge?" or "Please help me improve by code-challenge".

Comment: I suggest rewording so that someone skim-reading from the top doesn't get to "Otherwise, post it on main" and stop reading. The current wording looks likely to cause a repeat of Rusher's confusion this week.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Hmm, that's probably a good idea. What would you suggest rewording this as? I already bolded the "if it's a 'big list' question" and the "if it's opinion based or exceedingly broad" part. (Feel free to edit in any improvements you might want to make.)

Comment: Thanks for the overhaul, @PeterTaylor!

Comment: @PeterTaylor Are you referring to the "confusion" I had when a question I posted was incorrectly wiki'd by an overzealous mod?

Answer (score 4):

Doorknob's answer had to many points. By extracting this specific point and addressing it alone, we get a *clear* idea of what the community thinks.

> If it is a "big list" question but not so broad that a book could be
>   written to answer it, post it on main and flag for a mod to convert it
>   to Community Wiki.

**Downvote** if you think that *all* "Big List" questions should be encouraged.

**Upvote** if you think that "Big List" questions should be discouraged, but "Language Specific Tips" questions should be en exception to the rule because they already exist and are a precious resource for the PPCG community.

**Comment** if you think that all list questions, including tips, should be eradicated, unless someone else has clearly made that comment, in which case you should just upvote that comment.

Comment: FWIW, some sites (like Math.SE) go so far as to [have a big-list tag](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list) (bad idea IMO), and some just allow / don't actively prevent them, so there's something to think about if you're also active on an SE site that kills these on sight. (I do agree that these should be kept to a minimum, but I can't say I'd specifically *encourage* them.)