# Code trolling is dead. Now what?

Tags: discussion

## Code trolling [is officially no more!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1514/we-need-to-take-an-official-stance-on-code-trolling)

It has been 141 long days since [code-trolling] was first born. Now, every code trolling question is either locked or deleted. Code trolling is finally gone!

### What now?

In [Grace Note's progress report](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192/3808), it was mentioned:

> The invention of a new puzzle type, and perhaps continued innovation in that department, helps a lot.

Now that code trolling is dead, we're going to need to find another way to bring in more traffic.

- The [non-challenge questions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1555/3808) post has recieved only support, so we could start asking more of those.
- We could think of new challenge types (and make meta posts with the [new-genre](/questions/tagged/new-genre) tag to discuss them).
- Something else? Think of ideas for what you think would help in the answers!

### But what about *good* code trolling?

Or, what happens when someone thinks of a code trolling post we want?

In this case,

- the post should be tagged [popularity-contest] with a message specifying the type of answer and voting criteria there should be
- we should analyze the post, find out what makes it a "good" code trolling post, and then perhaps create a new tag based on this

### Anything else?

Yes. The point of this post is to push us even further to the graduation mark, for which we need a higher volume of high quality posts (and new users). Seeing as the previous "progress report" was quite... vague, not really giving us any concrete goals, I've pinged Grace Note requesting an updated "goals checklist" for the site's graduation.

Please post your own answers detailing what *you* think this site needs, until we get an "official" response from Grace and the SE team!

Comment: More KOTH. Great challanges, great answers, very popular, very funny.

Comment: +1 It seems to me that the only thing not "Excellent" on PPCG's Area 51 profile is the questions per day.  I am excited for us to get out of beta and think that some [new-genre]s would help with that.

Comment: Boo...feed the trolls...