# Should I accept an answer?

Tags: discussion

I couldn't find anything related to this on meta, so here goes:

I've noticed that we've decided that competitions should be within each language for a code-golf competition to avoid golfing languages winning all the time.

So, since it is a competition in each language, and we can't accept multiple answers for each language, I am asking whether to accept an answer at *all*.

Should PPCG question-askers be accepting an answer or should I not be accepting an answer for programming contests on PPCG?

Comment: [Related question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2035/how-long-should-i-wait-before-accepting-an-answer) with one of the answers specifically considering this.