# How do we know that our question can graduate from the sandbox?

Tags: support, sandbox

I have a couple of sandbox posts that have been there for a while. I have not posted them yet, though, because I don't know if they are ready...

How does one know if their ideas are ready to graduate from the sandbox?

Comment: My personal policy is that if it has +3, and no new comments for a few days, then it's fine. Alternatively, if it doesn't have many votes, then I assume no one is reading it, and post it to chat. If after doing this a couple of times it still has no votes, but there is no explicit negative feedback, then it's probably also fine, if not spectacular.

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7296/42963