# How to make question clear to users who voted to close without providing feedback as to what is not clear to them?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

This question [Permutations to the nines](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173145/permutations-to-the-nines) is "on hold" listing the reason as "unclear what you're asking".

Asked the first two users listed as voting to close what part of the question is not clear to them, to which no reply has been posted.

Am considering re-asking the question, though before doing so am seeking clarification here as to what part of the question could use improvement.

How to make question clear to users who voted to close without providing feedback as to what is not clear to them?

Answer (score 6):

> Asked the first two users listed as voting to close what part of the question is not clear to them, to which no reply has been posted.

Putting `@username` in a comment doesn't always notify the user. I'm not sure of the exact list of behaviours which make a user available to be pinged like that, but empirically it doesn't include casting a close vote, because I was not notified of your comment.

---

> Am considering re-asking the question, though before doing so am seeking clarification here as to what part of the question could use improvement.

We have a process for asking how a question could be improved. Full details in [How does the Sandbox work? How do I use it?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2056/194) . Rather than re-ask the question I suggest that you copy its content to an answer in the sandbox, self-delete the question, and then after the sandboxing process is over edit the original question and undelete. If it doesn't get reopened in a reasonable period (12 hours, say) then post in chat and you'll probably get enough reopen votes.

---

Finally, although this meta question isn't tagged [specific-question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-question), let me say that I didn't comment on what specifically was unclear about the question because I can't succinctly point to one thing which is unclear. The whole question seems to me to be a complicated mess, and I can't untangle which parts are directly relevant vs context for why the core question is interesting. IMO it needs a TL;DR which is no more than a quarter of the length of the current question and which stands alone and contains a full specification.

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16961/31257

Comment: The close voter can be pinged if they're the only one who votes to close: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Comment: @user202729 Composed a simplified version of the original question https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16978/31257