# Mixed input output methods in Brain-Flak and Stack based languages

Tags: discussion

It seems to be the consensus that it is acceptable in Brain-Flak to decompose a list into a series of arguments when taking input.

For example if you are to take the list `[2,5,6]` as input you may run the following Brain-Flak

```
ruby brain_flak.rb file 2 5 6
```

The same is also true of output, if you need to output the list `[4,5,9]` your program could print:

```
4
5
9
```

Other data types have other conventions, for example boolean values have [their own meta question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/truthiness-in-brain-flak-and-similar-stack-based-languages) dictating what is acceptable.

The current consensus on all of these i/o methods makes sense however things get a little strange when you start mixing datatypes in your i/o

For example if you need to take both an integer and a list as input how do you do so?

If your list is `[7,1,8]` and your integer is `2` can you run:

```
ruby brain_flak.rb file 7 1 8 2
```

How about:

```
ruby brain_flak.rb file 2 7 1 8
```

And for Truthy values things get even murkier, if I need to output `7`,`True` is

```
7
8
0
6
```

valid output?  Normally

```
8
0
6
```

would be Truthy value on its own but it seems a little like cheating when other values start showing up.

How do we take mixed type i/o for programming languages that have similar memory structures to Brain-Flak?