# Can Java lambdas reuse their named arguments to remove type declarations?

Tags: support, java

From what I have seen so far the usual way of scoring in java is by using lambda expressions. I often see [Try it online](https://tio.run/#java-jdk) used for it.
My actual question comes now:

Can you reuse the name of a named lambda to define a variable, thus allowing you to remove the `var`? For example, normally you'd do:

```
f -> {var s = ""; /* rest of the code */}
```

Are you allowed to make `f` a `String` to save a few characters? It'd then look like this:

```
f -> {f = ""; /* rest of the code */}
```

Comment: As for the second question, so long as it works as intended (aka, gives the correct output), there's almost no limitations aside from our [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)

Comment: That helps a lot, Thanks!!

Comment: One more related thing. If my task is to print the string "Foo", I'd not be allowed to pass that string in through the lambda right? That'd be nonsensical.

Comment: @Jadefalke no, your answer needs to be self-contained in that respect.

Comment: I've removed the first question from the question, as that's the only duplicate. The second question is a legitimate question that I'm not sure has been asked before, so I've changed the focus of the question to that. Feel free to revert any changes you dislike

Comment: I would say that the second shouldn't be allowed because although you're not using the *value* of `f`, you're taking advantage of its *type*. The input `f` shouldn't be mentioned anywhere in your lambda other than the parameter list because it's supposed to not even exist.

Comment: I get your point. That was my struggle in the first place. The previous answer thought it was ok. I'm a little confused right now, especially because I just scored using this method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing `f->{/*code*/}` is absolutely alright, as agreed upon in the [question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12681/are-we-allowed-to-use-empty-input-we-wont-use-when-no-input-is-asked-regarding) Dude coinheringaahing linked.

However, I would say that the second shouldn't be allowed because although you're not using the *value* of `f`, you're taking advantage of its type. In my opinion, the input `f` shouldn't be mentioned anywhere in your lambda other than the parameter list because it's really not even supposed to exist - it's just meant to save a byte over `()->{...}`.

Comment: Oh hang on, does Java require you to pass a string to the lambda for the answer to work? I was thinking from a JS perspective where it's work fine if you didn't pass anything.

Comment: To the answer: I believe that solves it. I'm gonna go with that now and change my answer!

Comment: @BrowncatPrograms Yes (or `null`, since strings are objects).