# Is boiler-plate code required for challenges?

Tags: discussion, answers

When solving a puzzle with an appropriate solution, does the programming language standard boiler-plate source code need to be included:

For example, should I include all of this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Code Golfing Is My Favourite Sport!");
    }
}
```

Alternatively, is it enough to include the actual specific code which solves the challenge, i.e.:

```
Console.WriteLine("Code Golfing Is My Favourite Sport!");
```

Comment: Submissions should be either a program or a function, not a snippet. If you choose to submit a program -- yes, a function -- language-dependent and we don't really have a clear consensus.

Comment: See https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet

Comment: Closures and fuctions are legal, but snippets are not. That is a snippet.