# Not halt to prevent display from disappearing

Tags: discussion

According to [Can Halting be considered output?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12310/) and maybe some other links, programs should halt. However in some cases making program halt is easier(save the infinite loop in code-golf, etc.) but making it almost impossible to see the result; or for some environment there's just no such thing "halt". What's the standard in this case?

Answer (score 3):

## Yes

I'd expect that the output is [displayed on the screen](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7139/69850) in that case.

In fact most Vim submissions on this site doesn't halt after execution (the process doesn't stop)

---

However, in common cases, the output won't "disappear" when the program is ended if it's run in a console.

Comment: Yet as shown allowing not-halt may give unfair advantages to these lang?