# Choosing outputs for challenges

Tags: discussion, policy, code-golf, answers

When the program you write for a challenge writes/outputs to multiple of the [default outputs](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), are you, the answerer allowed to state which one is counted for the purposes for the challenge?

For example, if my program

- Leaves the output on the stack
- Outputs to STDOUT

Am I allowed to say that the output to stdout counts without having to clean up the stack?

Comment: I feel like there are a lot of rather subtle issues to this. We generally ignore STDERR. But probably wouldn't accept a function submission whose outputs is its return value that prints to STDOUT as a side effect (or maybe I would? I don't even know). In your case: if the submission is a program, it can have whatever state you want at the end of the program. But if it's a function, I'd expect it to leave the stack clean and reusable. So I think what I'm saying is, there's a lot cases to distinguish here.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I've seen solutions that are functions that output by printing and have a return value that is ignored, and nobody complained, so that seems to be precedent for ignoring some form of outputs.

Comment: @xnor I think with "normal" functions and return values it's less of an issue because in most languages you explicitly need to capture the return value if you actually want it, and ignoring it is free. In stack-based languages, leaving unwanted stuff on the stack in a function is a bigger problem, because you'll have to remove it manually if you want your stack back.

Comment: Being able to say which output is counted kinda feels like cheating. "Oh, just ignore anything that isn't the correct output."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Yes, you can choose the output.

In fact, this is already what we do.

- A full program that prints to STDOUT will also terminate with a certain exit code, and [exit codes are a valid form of output](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5330/12012).

  Per consensus, [programs are allowed to terminate with an error](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4781/12012) after producing the correct output, so we're ignoring the exit code here.

  We also allow C programs which do not include `return 0` at the end. This is undefined behavior in C89, so the exit code could literally be anything.
- We allow a function to print the output to STDOUT, since [it may output via the same methods as full programs](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2457/12012).

  In many languages, the function will also have a return value. We ignore the return value of the function in this case.
- At this moment, the proposal of [printing output to STDERR](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2451/12012) has a positive score, yet [STDERR is ignored by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4781/12012).
- [Functions may output by modifying their arguments](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4942/12012), but if we print or return the desired result, we do not have to leave the arguments in a specific state.

Trying to specify which kinds of output can be ignored and which cannot seems artificial and will probably be ambiguous.

I therefore propose that we can liberally choose a single output format and ignore any results or side effects that could alternatively be chosen as output, with the following restriction.

The output format should be consistent for all possible inputs and every time the program/function is executed. The function

```
def primality_test(integer):
    print True
    return False
```

correctly prints *True* for primes and correctly returns *False* for non-primes, but it obviously should *not* be considered a valid submission to a challenge.