# Is outputting a Maybe acceptable in Haskell?

Tags: discussion, policy

> **The vote on this output option has moved [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14275/24877).**

Haskell has a *very strong* type system, so there is a type called `Maybe` to work around some restrictions.

> The Maybe type is defined as follows:
>
> ```
> data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
>     deriving (Eq, Ord)
> ```
>
> It allows the programmer to specify something may not be there.

<sup>From [the Haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Maybe).</sup>

Essentially, instead of erroring out, a function can return a `Maybe` that is either a `Just x` where `x` is the intended output or it can return `Nothing`, which indicates that there is no possible output.

One example is the second solution in [one of my answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146577/68615). As you can see, in the output, the answer asked for is `Just`  prefixed.

This can be fixed by applying `foldl1 seq` to the result, which I think is the golfiest way to do this.

Is outputting a `Maybe` valid?

<sup><sub>*Maybe* we can allow this...</sub></sup>

Comment: This can be generalised to any kind of Optional Type, that could either return `x` or `nil` or something equivalent.

Comment: @NathanMerrill There needs to be a consensus before the post goes in there, no?

Comment: No.  That post is where we decide the consensus.   Occasionally, if the issue is nuanced, or is hard to express using only a single up/down vote, then a secondary post occurs.

Comment: Well, I'd say I'd rather have a complete meta post with 2 (or more answers) than stuffing the same answers into the Default I/O post. Are you suggesting posting multiple options on that post?

Comment: Sorry, missed your last comment.  I'm suggesting that we post multiple answers to that post (one for each option).  We currently do that for pretty much every default.

Comment: ...Okay... does the clear consensus on this post still count now that it's a duplicate?

Comment: Nitpick: Defining `Maybe` as mentioned in the Haskell wiki is not the way it is defined. Try `data Mby a = Jst a | Nope deriving (Eq, Ord)` and then `(+1) <$> Jst 41` which will complain that `Mby` is not an instance of `Functor` whereas the real `Maybe` certainly is and it implements a lot of other classes too (check `:info Maybe` in `ghci`)..

Answer (score 14):

## Yes

Maybe is used to emulate failure in Haskell. The equivalent question in, say, Python, is

> is it OK that a submission could, in theory, return `None`, even though it never does?

or

> is it OK that a submission could, in theory, raise an exception, even though it never does?

The answers to these are obvious.

What the type system allows the submission to do ≠ what the submission actually does.

Also, a Maybe is equivalent to a list restricted to 0 or 1 elements, so the consensus about singleton lists could apply here.

Comment: Another valid "wrapper" is curried return types.  We allow returning a function that returns the value.

Comment: So this counts for the `[]` too then because it is often used to emulate failure as well? For example returning `a` wrapped in a list for a success or the empty list in case of a failure.

Comment: Can I ask you to post this answer on the [Default I/O post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)?

Comment: @totallyhuman [Added](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14275/61384).

Answer (score 1):

## As long as the function is guaranteed to not output `Nothing`, it is valid

The title explains it all. If the function is not supposed to return `Maybe` and it is guaranteed to not output `Nothing`, it is valid.