# Should rust anonymous functions fully specify parameter types?

Tags: discussion, languages

### Context

Rust does a lot of smart things to determine the types of variables. This is why you rarely need to define the types of a variable explicitly. Rust can search very far to find a type for a function. For example, this is invalid:

```
let i;
```

but this is valid:

```rs
let i;
i=5
```

These lines do not need to be next to eachother. There can be a lot of code in between.

### Problem

Consider this rust answer:

```
|a,b|a;
```

This won't compile. You need to specify the type for `a` and `b`. To make this compile you would need

```rs
|a:u8,b:u8|a;
```

However, often rust answers have test cases, so the full code will look more like this:

```rs
fn main(){
f = 
|a,b|a;

asserteq!(f(1,2), 1);
}
```

This compiles, the test case in this case tells rust the type of the function, even though it appears much later in the code.

Many answers use this trick so save bytes, for example:

- [It's just Rocket Science](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252272/91213) Here the type of `m` is unspecified.
- [Do 2 numbers contain unique powers of 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250055/91213) Both `a` and `b` are missing types
- [All Possible Ties in Tic-Tac-Toe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249948/91213) My own answer
- [How many light changes will a 7-segment display need?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248129/91213)
- [Finding prime numbers without using "prime characters"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/245739/91213) The TIO link for this answer even explicitly types the function but doesn't include that in the byte count

Not criticizing any of these answers, there where all valid when posted.

There might also be cases when the test cases accidentally limit the return type too, or the type of a global variable. Just listing those for argument types since the issue is easier to spot but it's not the only way the type can be defined outside the block itself.

### Question

Should it be allowed for the types of arguments in rust (and maybe other languages that have implicit static typing) be allowed to derive from test cases?

Comment: Related issue in C# with no clear consensus: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10974/91213

Comment: As someone who's responsible for a fair number of these answers, the standard I've used is "can coerce into an appropriately typed function pointer", mainly to avoid cluttering up the test cases with type annotations. I've upvoted Bubbler's answer because it's mostly equivalent and more in line with site precedent.

Comment: Haskell already does this.

Comment: I think this question is answered in https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11223/untyped-functions-in-static-languages

Answer (score 14):

## If Rust's type inference can infer argument types using external information, it is OK to omit them

There is a precedent for [Haskell](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14281/78410) allowing this.

But note that *Rust's* type inference is a lot weaker than e.g. Haskell's. If you omit types when Rust can't infer them even with context, your answer is invalid, and should be fixed to include the types so that the code compiles.

Comment: +1 Husk, too, does this all the time. In fact, if I'm not mistaken, the *parsing* of a Husk program can be affected by what argument types are passed to it.

Comment: Arguably that's not just a precedent in Haskell. That question uses Haskell as an example but it asks in general and the top voted answer makes no mention of a specific language.

Answer (score 4):

## Implicit parameter types should be allowed

We write code to be used. If the compiler can implicitly infer the types by calling the function the exact same way you would with explicit parameter types, and with the exact same output, it should be allowed.