# Should the standard loophole meta thread have the featured tag?

Tags: discussion

Almost all of our challenges on PPCG have the implied rule of no standard loopholes. However, I have seen many answers (mainly from new users) that contain some of these standard loopholes. Should we feature the [standard loophole thread](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) to allow for easier accessing of the information to new and curious users, and lower the chance of these invalid answers?

Answer (score 19):

### Yes, via FAQ Hub thread

Similar to Mego's answer, but why not feature the [FAQ hub thread](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1280/community-faq-for-programming-puzzles-code-golf), as all of the FAQ threads need more visibility.

Comment: Side note: Should we add [default I/O methods](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) to the FAQ Hub?

Comment: I think the fewer things that are featured at once, the better. Thus it makes more sense to me to feature this, which is a collection of resources, rather than a single resource.

Comment: Adding the I/O defaults to the FAQ hub isn't necessary because it's been incorporated into the code golf tag wiki.

Comment: So the answer is not "Yes". It's "No, it should be part of the FAQ instead."

Answer (score 6):

### Yes

More visibility for that thread is good. I would also suggest making the [default I/O methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) post featured as well. The meta featured posts could become sort of a newbie center, since we apparently can't modify the tour.