# How does the community work?

Tags: discussion

How does this Programming Puzzles & Code Golf work?
Just curious because I don't really know what this is and I want to fined out...

Comment: Hi and welcome to PPCG! This is a Q&A-style site where users write programming challenges and post responses that match particular criteria, usually [tag:code-golf]. For now, however, I've voted to move your question to Meta, which is for discussion *about* PPCG, as the main site is almost exclusively reserved for challenges.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want to know, but there are a number of frequently asked questions guides that may help: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1280/community-faq-for-programming-puzzles-code-golf

Comment: If I had to sum it up in a sentence, I'd say this is a community of friendly and helpful programmers who enjoy setting and competing in well defined competitions.